# Sum of primes between given range

Tags: code-golf, primes

Write the shortest code for finding the sum of primes between \$a\$ and \$b\$ (inclusive).

**Input**

1. \$a\$ and \$b\$ can be taken from command line or stdin (space seperated)
2. Assume \$1 \le a \le b \le 10^8\$

**Output**
Just print the sum with a newline character.

**Bonus Points**

1. If the program accepts multiple ranges (print one sum on each line), you get extra points. :)

Comment: The upper limit is too big to allow many interesting solutions (if they have to complete in reasonable time, at least).

Comment: @hallvabo You find inefficient solutions interesting?

Comment: @hallvabo, That's ok. I don't think anyone minds an ineffcient solution. If other's object, i'll be more than happy to lower the limit

Comment: Just made and ran a not very optimised or concise version of the program in C#, using 1 to 10^8. Assuming my algorithm's correct, it ran in under 1m30s, and didn't overflow from a long. Seems like a fine upper limit to me!

Comment: A quick easy check: sum of primes between 1 and 100 = 1060.

Comment: @Matthew Read, *You find inefficient solutions interesting?* - you didn't specify effectiveness, so either specify, or decrease upper limit, or we will decrease it in our solutions.

Comment: @st0le So seperated by spaces would be something like `2 3 5` and that would be ranges `2 3` and `3 5`?

Comment: @jamylak, you can assume the numbers will always appear in pairs.

Comment: @st0le Ahh ok I will change my solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## J,<sup><strike>41</strike> <strike>32</strike></sup> 19 characters:

*Update*

(simple sieve)

```
g=:+/@(*1&p:)@-.&i.
```

e.g.

```
100 g 1
1060
250000x g 48
2623030823
```

*Previous*

```
h=:3 :'+/p:i.(_1 p:>:y)'
f=:-&h<:
```

eg:

```
100 f 1
1060
```

Answer (score 11):

### Mathematica 7 (31 chars in plain text)

If PARI/GP solution allowed, then:

```
Plus@@Select[Range[a,b],PrimeQ]
```

Comment: What's your point? PARI/GP and Mathematica are fine programming languages.

Comment: @Eelvex, no, they break one of golf rules: *using built-in specific highlevel functions*.

Comment: I don't think there is such a *rule*. It's still an open matter when to use highlevel functions. See for ex. [this meta question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23/use-of-built-in-functions-and-libraries-in-code-golfs)

Comment: 28 chars `Range[a,b]~Select~PrimeQ//Tr`.

Answer (score 6):

## C#, 294 characters

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){int a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),b=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());long t=0;for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)if(p(i))t+=i;Console.WriteLine(t);}static bool p(int n){if((n%2<1&&n!=2)||n<2)return 0>1;for(int i=3;i<=Math.Sqrt(n);i+=2)if(n%i==0)return 0>1;return 1>0;}}
```

Comment: You can make all your `int`s `long` and save a few characters: `long a=...,b=...,t=0,i=a;for(;i<=b;i++)`. This gets it to 288 chars. You can also let `p` return a long and just return either `0` or `n` and shorten the loop to `t+=p(i)`. 277 chars, then.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 117 bytes

```
main(a,b,s,j){
s=0,scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
for(a+=a==1;a<=b;a++)
for(s+=a,j=2;j<a;)
s-=a%j++?0:(j=a);
printf("%d",s);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 183 characters

```
using System;class P{static void Main(string[] a){long s=0,i=Math.Max(int.Parse(a[0]),2),j;for(;i<=int.Parse(a[1]);s+=i++)for(j=2;j<i;)if(i%j++==0){s-=i;break;}Console.WriteLine(s);}}
```

This would be much shorter if it didn't have to check for 1, or if there was a better way to... In a more readable format:

```
using System;
class P 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] a) 
    { 
        long s = 0,
             i = Math.Max(int.Parse(a[0]),2),
             j;

        for (; i <= int.Parse(a[1]);s+=i++)
            for (j = 2; j < i; )
                if (i % j++ == 0)
                {
                    s -= i;
                    break;
                }

        Console.WriteLine(s); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how short this is, but I wonder how inefficient it would be when calculating up to 10^8!

Comment: True, but efficiency wasn't in the rules!

Comment: You know the compiler defaults numerics to 0 right? That'ld save you a couple more chars in there

Comment: Gives error when compiled without it

Comment: ...because it is never assigned before it is used (via `s -= i;` because thats just syntactic sugar for `s = s - i;` which tries to access `s` before setting it)

Comment: @jcolebrand, that's only true of fields, local variables have to be initialized.

Comment: You can save a character by using `string[]a`in the `Main` signature. Antother two by omitting the call to `Math.Max` and instead using `int i=int.Parse(a[0]);i=2<i?i:2;`. The latter can even be pulled into the `for` header to save another char for the `;`.

Answer (score 4):

## PARI/GP, 44 characters

```
sum(x=nextprime(a),precprime(b),x*isprime(x))
```

Comment: Shouldn't down voters give a reason for their -1?

Comment: The downvote was probably for using built-ins.

Answer (score 4):

## BASH Shell, 47 Characters

```
seq 1 100|factor|awk 'NF==2{s+=$2}END{print s}'
```

Edit: Just realized the sum overflows and is coerced as a double.

#### <strike>52</strike> 50 Characters

Here's a bit longer solution, but handles overflows aswell

```
seq 1 100|factor|awk NF==2{print\$2}|paste -sd+|bc
```

Comment: tr is shorter than paste, and you can remove the single quotes (escape the `$`).

Comment: @Nabb, will fix it as soon as i get my hands on a *nix box, or you could do the honours.

Comment: @Nabb, can't get it to work, `tr` adds a trailing '+' at the end, fixing it will take more chars.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Although I think you can still change to `awk NF==2{print\$2}` to save a byte on the longer solution (we won't accidentally run into brace expansion because there are no commas or `..`s).

Comment: @Nabb, you're right. Done :)

Comment: @st0le : what do you mean coerced ?  `jot - 3 100000000 2 | mawk2 '(__=$NF)<(_+=_^=___)*++_ || __%_*/[1379]$/' | gfactor | pvE0 | mawk2 'BEGIN{__=_+=++_}{_+=$(NF=__==NF)}END{print _}'` :::::::::::::::::::: `in0:  530MiB 0:00:12 [41.1MiB/s] [41.1MiB/s] [ <=> ]` :::::::::::::::::::::::: 
`279209790387276`. If you skip the last 8-digit prime the sum it outputs is `279209690387287` - no truncation, "double coercion", or loss of precision at all

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell (80)

```
c=u[2..];u(p:xs)=p:u[x|x<-xs,x`mod`p>0];s a b=(sum.filter(>=a).takeWhile(<=b))c
```

`s 1 100 == 1060`

Comment: This is code-golf! Why do you use such long names for your stuff?

Comment: It's hard to find shorter names than c, u, s...  The rest is language standard library.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 62 chars

```
<>=~/\d+/;map$s+=$_*(1x$_)!~/^1$|(^11+)\1+$/,$&..$';print$s,$/
```

This one uses the prime number regex.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby 1.9, 63 chars

```
require'prime';p=->a,b{Prime.each(b).select{|x|x>a}.inject(:+)}
```

Use like this

```
p[1,100] #=> 1060
```

Using the `Prime` class feels like cheating, but since the Mathematica solutions used built-in prime functions...

Answer (score 3):

### APL (25 characters)

```
+/((R≥⎕)^~R∊R∘.×R)/R←1↓⍳⎕
```

This is a modification of a well-known idiom (see [this page](http://www.users.cloud9.net/%7Ebradmcc/APL.html) for an explanation) for generating a list of primes in APL.

Example:

```
      +/((R≥⎕)^~R∊R∘.×R)/R←1↓⍳⎕
⎕:
      100
⎕:
      1
1060
```

Answer (score 3):

### Normal Task (Python 3): 95 chars

```
a,b=map(int,input().split())
r=range
print(sum(1%i*all(i%j for j in r(2,i))*i for i in r(a,b+1)))
```

### Bonus Task (Python 3): 119 chars

```
L=iter(map(int,input().split()))
r=range
for a,b in zip(L,L):print(sum(1%i*all(i%j for j in r(2,i))*i for i in r(a,b+1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 57 characters

```
a=scan();b=a[1]:a[2];sum(b[rowSums(!outer(b,b,`%%`))==2])
```

Comment: Is specifying `n=2` necessary in `scan()`? If the input is standard, is there a problem with omitting the argument and assuming an extra <enter> is required?

Comment: No actually you're right I could have done without. It was purely for aesthetic reasons (since i knew my code wasn't the shortest anyway :) )

Comment: Well, +1 from me just the same, as it's definitely not the longest.

Answer (score 3):

## Pari/GP (24 characters)

```
s=0;forprime(i=a,b,s+=i)
```

Like some other solutions, this doesn't strictly meet the requirements, as `a` and `b` aren't read from stdin or the command line.  I thought it was a nice alternative to the other Pari/GP and Mathematica solutions however.

Comment: +1: This is the way I'd actually do it, even without golfing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
òV fj x
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8lYgZmogeA==&input=MgoyMw==)

Comment: Welcome to Japt :)

Comment: @Shaggy I originally tried to find a "prime range" builtin in Japt, but then decided to accept the challenge :p

Comment: Given how many challenges there are related to primes, a shortcut for `fj<space>` could be handy.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ŸDp*O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6A6XAi3///@jDXUMDQxiAQ)

```
Ÿ      Push the list [a, ..., b]
 D     Push a duplicate of that list
  p    Replace primes with 1 and everything else with 0
   *   Element-wise multiply the two lists [1*0, 2*1, 3*1, 4*0, ...]
    O  Sum of the final list of primes
```

Comment: ✓ I didn't think of using `p*`

Comment: More boring solution with filter: `Ÿʒp}O`

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>164</s> <s>138</s> 122 bytes

```c
i,x,y,z;main(f){for(scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);x<y;z+=x++*!f)if(f=0,x<2)++x;else for(i=2;x/2/i&&!(f|=x%i++<1););printf("%i",z);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxbDoIwEADAqxQMTWurPH639S6kZXUTLAYwWVDPXsMBZsIljH265xOlML7jINyyRpquj1smy3azOzx7Sgr1B6dZLaFPqMoqiiqWVrKVmwZ2G@zGszHnAjWhQt9Ydp02hmEYl0EclHwHXHc1SVko/HquyBjXatDwmimtR0ul3TX8cm5F2zR/)

Original code from [Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/prime-number-intervals). Just modified the code to reduce bytes. Yes, I'm terrible at this.

Code changed thanks to Pedro Maimere, byte count didn't change. Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing 26 bytes, and another 16 bytes.

Comment: As is, your code is not adding `y`, if prime. You have to use `while(x<=y)` instead, adding one byte. On the other side, you can omit one space here: `"%d %d"`.[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU5ZDsIgFLxKU9MGAmqtn694F2TRFys1XSJtw9kR/JuZzKaOqpfuEQ/oVL9oU3TTrHE4PW8R3Vy8JTpC9wwtR@75yjfRwKSks6SsdKVLXnterxS@T@wN8Z1Y6W6TB20iLd0Z86AGN6NbDAQ7jARFC9gJf26BMUztyVmhEE0OXuA@GvmCEJJs/@LGhIeQe8JnTFfyMpZ8oxBibIvrDw "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
$+Y1=0N_%,_FIa\,b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYbVbQjDW0N_OJVdeLdPBNjdJIg4lDp5dFGOgpGxrFQLgA)

*-2 thanks to @DLosc*

Uses [DLosc's answer to the prime checker challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57701/114446)

##### Explanation

```lisp
$+Y1=0N_%,_FIa\,b  ; Input on command line
              \,   ; Inclusive range between
             a  b  ; The two inputs
           FI      ; Filtered by
   1=0N_%,_        ; Is prime (see linked answer)
$+                 ; Sum the resulting list
```

Old:

```lisp
$+Y{1=0Na%,a}FIa,Ub  ; Input on command line
                ,    ; Range between
               a     ; The first input
                 Ub  ; To the second input incremented
             FI      ; Filtered by
   {1=0Na%,a}        ; Is prime (see linked answer)
$+Y                  ; Sum the resulting list
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYbVbQjDW0N_OJVdeLdPBNjdJIg4lDp5dFGOgpGxrFQLgA)

Comment: @DLosc thanks, updated

Comment: "see linked answer" yet there's no linked answer :(

Comment: @AidenChow sorry, I removed the link

Answer (score 3):

## Regex  (ECMAScript<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/)</sup> / Perl / PCRE), 32 bytes

```
^(x*),x*(?=\1)(?!(xx+)\2+$)x\Bx*
```

Takes its input in unary, as two strings of `x` characters whose lengths represent the numbers, joined by a `,` delimiter, specifying an inclusive range. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU@9TsMwEN79FId1g52Y1gnqUjdNi8rKxBhhlaiVUrlJSIJkFMzIA/CIvEi4ggTj93vftYfOLabzK2BnYHRNuXeAc0MwW@22D9t1YMemE9hn2qzWRo5QHQnJse2qegBe1NwEUhOKuKx/eeoHclt1nahEHp4vev7PauLlEq2hFhDoqG5DqdZVg@CKK2IMA8CSrsGpqeof9rxvR@65Rxs2Tmbvc5EvsZMiz8c4xlLpIGnx76C/EDlnHL4@PoHPsKR1b7SRhWDt3f3O2ulR@EgqH4k8KxLquhLex7JIY5S@uPXRNNEHmiVapZqlKr1hF6y/AQ) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU89TsMwFN5zioflwU7c1gkLqpumRWVlYoywStRIQW4SklQyCmbkAKwsHeAIPUxXjsAJeCUIJuv7fZ_f3utNY_bHr-0j0EZBb6psbYBOFMJ4tlreLOfOy6uG0TaWajZXvIciR8T7uinKDkhaEuVQDTFi4nZ313bo1mIUipBvHk568s9K5PmUaoUtwKjBugWmalN0jAgikFEeAM3wGtxXRfnDbtd1TyyxVLuF4fHzhCVT2nCWJH0Q0ExIx3HxMOgvhM4xgc-XVyBjmuG6J9zoOaf11fVK649dl48ujnDLrM-F9VkSpyFWnjFrA55GAeU2vbT-4Nv_Pgf8lfRCKSLpRSI6905YDuI3) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVThbts2EP6vp7i4a0xaTCDZwFBYUYM2zbAfWTMYKbAhzgSFpmwhMiVQ0uyk9d8@QB@xDzLvSEq23KSGLVPHu@@7@45HXhQnc863r1LJs3om4KzgSpwu3jp8ESuIits7CGHSe79aPdyP6r8fH/@6Wfy6WpDtP2Q9oGw9IOfh1Kfk/Iis1y6dDt1f6Hr6fj3Y0h9jegwGRRgVrh84e76ymqW5JuyaVCrnh7Y0R6uIl8/93jqprKDAZRUJpXJFeC7LCkwBg6Uoy3gu6GfkGY85OsDZGTRWvTR2IWdZAEpUtZLgBxunlmU6l2IGWS7n9hHLciVUYNiWjxGPsyyvK6L1al@i@yznDzDgFD5bd9fdwXoIa2LjVBJ0cAA/xS0WkQlJCnri34VeADYhWxoUPOyR83EvwJUbFvavh2pfaMUp2muEHA2jCnIdrPHnuDDYXaBUFnWlw5WAgRIBdDVCUYpK2Wglyjqr7FqrmSSlqBhgcZjlvFrYnfxfwatc3Y7uLBWihmCVyJdFmgmU5ZRHSE4ogz8vJpfRh@ubd1dX8MW@fbr57Q2DY8tsFy2VRy1mmgA5UoK2@iWmxQnBstCbQU8DmRwVxJiSCYfXszG8LqcSD1sH0/I0wN2OYdr7XtrtBPGILvJJK2pEnIsqS6Ug9gylklk9adC2sc33iQLataqkP5V9GiCIH5gtE3Fapk@C0DD0qO5AlcpaBHsEJEWVNa1tTLnf22VV5CU6HDC3sVKsIoxnILGsuMrThrRpBLg6mAaHcZiatv4Atzs/XIuEY9JjveC5B/IQneqA4myihpyUDEiTB27qpws@/qSm9@kLGLfo5Lr6mumz/uH@BkRWipdS2xMvLW@H9EWqzcHbUizxXJASHY1g/XUfVcN2mWw0hkXTWbWHoFVCHgKjeOhkhU5SOSNYBTNWk0QrMIRhdyDHY2lUv0fdHgLrHuLN4zzP97AN8P3rN8C5t9eLSW/naWe3nUSxFpwoweDjp6srBtgYU6pnvs0AMxh1dNKpWowzD46PW7yj0M7s5WRyPYk@Xv/x7ubid@r8/Khc6pnsHBfdxJ@7N5W0V3GS1eXihZqaOjeOmfixHVUlBGZMd3dsc3s5m63PfM/xPTb0nCEbjhz97v3Hkyyel9uTTCv0Pw) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTuNGFP6fpzh4KzLjGBoHdYViDGIhEpEgrLJB3S5QyziTxMIeW74sgZa/fYA@Yh@k9MzFjkOyagTJzJlzvnOdb4I03ZsHwduHKZuFnMHns/Gg551dnw@8m9Fw4v06PJ9cwGHrQ8iDqJwyOEqDjPX2F8etYOFn4KW39@DC2Pj09PT4cFD@9vz8dbL4@LQgb7@TpUmtpUlO3DubkpMdslx26F2v8xNd3n1amm/0vY1hgZm6XtqxnYbDvMhCPhceV7IwQSnz4@MNveNWyAtIcVl4LMuSjAQJzwuQ0Zoxy3N/zij8kRfTfj9ADTg6Ai0WSylnfBo5kLGizDjYzusGptgHyZRZ8JAkESTuzI9yASvdaLjb3i8f750W4CecAZGF8@ZMY3haiygcoip/c3ZxOj40qT60IA9fWDIjdeA/V5KGPqVUehEfksCJSiJIygL6UCdKRXqGNAMZQR@Md8lLY8NAK@OOG7Suxywq84XKpC5K67VV8jycczaFKOFz9eXz/IlljixY/OwFfhRhGDp3vfMeoiR4BDOw4HsSTsGc@oWPtRNFEktwXSDixKS7KwyqsTudujNd3ZnYDzlBABlgeouDEDFOUrpn37tdR6WgpgPSwDXISd9wcNVxU/Vj4HSeiQmlKC8R8aDnFdhUtBXwc1xI6CZQyNOyEOYyMWwhmBmr9rFfBAtP5mKu1gotY3kZFZZqgaMv3Jfht4GUzGY5w0PMF1OYF4s1BTP5zoICrXQn8OJV/uM0jBjRQ/Hl82RM02A/8DBYQi2N8W0wvvYmg/HVcHQ6GZxX4sHXyWB0PjiHP7Xg6uZyMrwcjgYW7Moo9a@OrUtXM72T4UjqbjTvh/zWeo1iuBv18XDvF8ybZUnspX5RsIyTDOd@dHN5qQGaNniZC7YssKzVyt12rmHJBgpmUA9lBWE1JtXaNnnvAZSrKIzDJsieTZ2G0pSlxf8qZSwoszxM@FZF6XaWZCD55qWeZeSQCMmaqKsdcktNI3WqO1C154UCygUnkfYdb6PrF9d25JG02BdcQqjrdikIzyEvmbNCQKc4hcKtYs98dVZHlSY5Kqx5rmw5e/LQ3gKOTfKLJNRO9VhCRxhTZ91OECVK38HVt0@SmuAxy3A2NdAPEaGaFNuPvQtIjg3VceCh@O6Ajf9cuLfpFoxbVOp0xKPWttrr56/AkOW3hbZyHCu/DadbXb2u7WIW4zSQHBVlwdrLNlYN2yWjERgKTURVDUFVCb4OjMVDJVVofNGnBLOwpFQGURVYcGyDzvp9Lqv@gHV7dJS6K0h@M971NsA/f/0NyJqKm2V4taZiuvULKu92k6awQTLlrvxbEQOu9V1oVE4Er1CPurC7qz3suJrIxuPrsTe6vjqdnF3Q9ao0uKki4CIrWQNbtLb1w3nT@W15EF9/xFHIaYyRVRab3KcU6j1tPifqEOm1fu1U3PjuvtmW3W3ZXavXbfWs3kFL7Lv/BrPIn@dve5EE2Tv8Dw) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbdTuNGFL5unuLgrciMY2gS1BWKMYiFSETiZ5UN6naBWsaZJBbO2LLHS6Dltg_Q2970ppd72YfZXvZJeubHjkNSNSLOzJlzvvM7n_n9S5jGRS6__jQMv9xYO3EaZqy7s2_dfR2-GbNJxBm8Pxn2u_7J1Wnfv74cjPwfBqejM9hvvIl4GBdjBgfKaHd22AhnQQZ-enMHHgytd4-PD_d7xY9PTx9Hs7ePM_JnISY7-1_hJ7KwqbOwyZF326HkaIssFi162219Sxe37xa21vv7m336GsJywE49P2113Jr_XGQRn8oAlrIoQSkL5odreoeNiAtIcSl8lmVJRsKE5wJU8Pac5XkwZRR-zsW41wtRAw4OwIjlUskZH8cuZEwUGYeO-7KGKfdhMmYO3CdJDIk3CeJcwio3Bu6m-_3bO7cB-IkmQFQd_SkzGL7RIhqH6EZcn5wdD_dtag4dyKNnlkxIFfh3paSmTylVXuSHJHCkkwiTQkAPqkSpTM9SZqAi6IH1KnllbFloZd1yi1b1mOAQzXQmVVEaL42C59GUszHECZ_qR8DzR5a5qmDzJz8M4hjDMLmbnX8fJ-ED2KEDn5NoDPY4EAHWThZJLsHzgMgTm24vMajBbrWqzrRNZ-ZBxAkCqADTGxyEmHGS0p3Ondd2dQp6OiANPYsc9SwXVy0v1T8WTumJnFSK8gIR97q-wKairYSf4kJB14EinhZCmqvEsIVgZ6zczwMRznyVi71ca7SM5UUsHN0C19y_D4NPfSWZTHKGh5gvpjAVsxUFO_nMQoFWphN4D0v_8zSKGTFD8eH9aEjTcDf0MVhCHYPxqT-88kf94cXg8njUPy3F_Y-j_uVp_xR-MYKL6_PR4Hxw2XdgW0Vpfk1sbbqc6a0MR9J0o34_1NPo1YrhrdXHx30gmD_JkrmfBkKwjJMM5_7y-vzcANRt8DILthBY1nLlbTo3sGQNBTOohrKEcGqT6myavNcA2lUczaM6yE6HujWlMUvF_yplLCyyPEr4RkXldpJkoPjmuZpl5JAYuZvoqx1xR08jdcs7ULbnmQLKJSeR5i1voutnr-OqI2WxK7mEUM9rU5CeI14wd4mATnEKpVvNnvnyrIoqTXJUWPFc2nL26KO9AxybFIgkMk7NWEJLGlN31U4SJUpfwVW3T5Ga5DHHctc10A-RodoU24-9C0mODTVx4KF8tqCDXy7dd-gGjBtUarXkO67pNFfPX4Ahy28Kbel4rv3WnG509bKym7M5TgPJUVEVrLloYtWwXSoaiaHRZFTlEJSV4KvAWDxU0oXGF_yYYBaOkqogygJLjq3RWa_HVdXvsW4Prlb3JMmvx7vaBvjn198AWVNzswqv0tRMt3pB1d2u0xQ2SKXcVn9LYsC1uQu1ysngNepBG7a3jYctzxDZcHg19C-vLo5HJ2d0tSo1bioJWGQFq2HL1q7YrCRq8tvwQnz5L45CTmOMLLNY5z6tUO1p_XWiD5Feq7edjhvfu_ofqD_-6jiddqPTdrrtRtfp7jXkvq0P_wU) - PCRE2
[Try it on replit.com!](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Sum-of-primes-between-given-range) - RegexMathEngine, in ECMAScript mode

```
^              # Anchor to start
(x*)           # \1 = lower end of range
,              # Skip over delimiter
x*             # tail += {any number, including zero}
(?=\1)         # Assert that tail ≥ \1
(?!(xx+)\2+$)  # Assert that tail is not composite (i.e., tail is prime or is < 2)
x\Bx*          # if tail ≥ 2, add tail to the number of possible matches; this is
               # equivalent to "(?=xx)x+"
```

## Regex (.NET), 32 bytes

```
x(x*),((?=(xx+)\3+$|(x)+)x\B)*\1
```

Returns its output as the capture count of group `\4`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9LboMwFEXnrMJCr8KPnyDpKAg1bcddAUEVpU5w5djINsIKYdoFdIndCCWVqg7vR1fn9mpk2nRMiAV0WWl2Yq7e7SQb6T5YHHUhxpQ@lNS5CA/bCK7UYYTu8IThIV@Cfew/q3PPBXv3sYBLmRVHpVnTdhQE4ZIAl/1gcYKmBJGYXnDrx35BwJUUGnIld2QKkiCkFZe2htdEWJJhFLggrF4a260wj2/mL8UZkw/F5e8EP1I4l6DTtdd2zFBwiNPNveA0am5Z0ilj55UqL8i/QRKp1oOCS0b8lfL784vAOpWetBp6U93Xadv0dtDMpK0apEV/npc8zjMvz@JN5m3izda76ewH)

```
                   # No need to anchor, as this regex will always match
x(x*)              # \1 = {lower end of range} - 1
                   # This takes advantage of the input specification allowing
                   # us to assume it to be ≥ 1.
,                  # Skip over delimiter; tail = upper end of range
(
    (?=            # Lookahead - is atomic (the first match found is final)
        (xx+)\3+$  # Match if tail is composite (i.e., isn't prime and is ≥ 2)
    |          # or...
        (x)+       # Push {tail} captures onto the Group 4 stack, i.e. add
                   # {tail} to the return value.
    )
    x              # tail -= 1
    \B             # Assert tail > 0
)*                 # Iterate the above as many times as possible (can be zero)
\1                 # Assert tail ≥ \1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 107 chars

```
(flet((p(i)(loop for j from 2 below i never (= (mod i j) 0))))(loop for x from(read)to(read)when(p x)sum x))
```

only works for starting points \$\ge 1\$

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3.1(153 chars):

```
from sys import*
p=[]
for i in range(int(argv[1]),int(argv[2])):
 r=1
 for j in range(2,int(argv[2])):
  if i%j==0and i!=j:r=0
 if r:p+=[i]
print(sum(p))
```

Comment: 1. `from sys import*` 2. `r=True` -> `r=1` (and respectively `0` for `False`) 3. `if i%j==0and i!=j:r=0` 4. `if r:p+=[i]` 5. `print(sum(p))` (replaces last 4 lines)

Comment: You can use `input()` to be shorter. Also, can you use `if i%j<1and` instead?

Answer (score 2):

### In Q (95):

```
d:{sum s:{if[2=x;:x];if[1=x;:0];$[0=x mod 2;0;0=min x mod 2+til floor sqrt x;0;x]}each x+til y}
```

Sample Usage:

```
q)d[1;100]
1060
```

Answer (score 2):

## Factor -> 98

```
:: s ( a b -- n )
:: i ( n -- ? )
n 1 - 2 [a,b] [ n swap mod 0 > ] all? ;
a b [a,b] [ i ] filter sum ;
```

Output:

```
( scratchpad ) 100 1000 s

--- Data stack:
75067
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 302 bytes

```
using System;namespace X{class B{static void Main(){long x=long.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),y=long.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),r=0;for(long i=x;i<=y;i++){if(I(i)){r+=i;}}Console.WriteLine(r);}static bool I(long n){bool b=true;if(n==1){b=false;}for(long i=2;i<n;++i){if(n%i==0){b=false;break;}}return b;}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 85 characters

`x=scan(nmax=2);sum(sapply(x[1]:x[2],function(n)if(n==2||all(n %% 2:(n-1)))n else 0))`

Extremely inefficient! I'm pretty sure it takes O(n^2) time. It might give warnings about coercing a double to a logical.

Deobfuscated:

```
x <- scan(nmax=2)
start <- x[1]
end <- x[2]

#this function returns n if n is prime, otherwise it returns 0.
return.prime <- function(n) {
  # if n is 2, n is prime. Otherwise, if, for each number y between 2 and n, n mod y is 0, then n must be prime
  is.prime <- n==2 || all(n%% 2:(n-1))
  if (is.prime)
    n
  else
    0
} 
primes <- sapply(start:end, return.prime)
sum(primes)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>239</s> <s>237</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```java
a->b->{long r=0,t;for(;a<=b;r-=b--==t?~b:0)for(t=1;b%++t%b>0;);return r;}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jU9Na4QwEL37K4aFBYMaom2hbDaWXnpqT3sUKcmuitZNJI5bROxft7G7tNdeZt58vXmvkRcZma7QzeljObay7@FN1nryAHqUWB@hcRt0wLql5aCPWBtNX25g/2p0Ff5jY41pCiUIWGSUqiidWtcCK1iIvDTW53IvFLeRUFEkBD59qR0j6wBFzNU2CHCrUsYJtwUOVoPl88I9p7IbVOtU3sReTH2CszPgH9DWuspyaauerHYAVrr1rWvudPEJV5zl05SEyd0cTnEYM@by/WOYPLB35oqZ/JwCHMYeizM1A9LOMWOr/T/fz9bKsadorl99SYLNDjZBSWXXtaMvM5aTXxznhHBHO3vz8g0)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->{              // Method with two Long parameters & Long return-type
  long r=0,          //  Result-sum, starting at 0
       t;            //  Temp-long
  for(;a<=b          //  Loop as long as `a` is still smaller than or equal to `b`:
      ;              //    After every iteration:
       r-=           //     Decrease the result-sum by:
          b--==t?    //      If `b` is equal to `t` (which means `b` is a prime):
                     //      (and decrease `b` by 1 afterwards with `b--`)
           ~b        //       Decrease the result-sum by `-b-1`
                     //       (aka Increase the result-sum by `b+1`,
                     //        where `+1` is to account for the earlier `b--`)
          :          //      Else:
           0)        //       Leave `r` the same by decreasing with 0
    for(t=1;         //   (Re)set `t` to 1
        b%++t%b>0;); //   Increase `t` by 1 first with `++t` every iteration,
                     //   and loop as long as `b` is NOT divisible by `t`,
                     //   and `b` is NOT 1 (with the second `%b`)
  return r;}         //  After the nested loop, return the result-sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
æRS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wsqDg////G/03MgYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](http://desmos.com/calculator), <s>124</s> 50 bytes

```
f(a,b)=∑_{n=a}^bnsgn((n-1)∏_{k=3}^nmod(n,k-1))
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gibosoovlc)

<s>I had to waste 23 bytes just for the edge case of 0 and 1(`-\left\{n<2:1,0\right\}`). I feel like this could definitely be golfed further, but I'm not that skilled at Desmos. I especially think that the edge cases 0 and 1 could be handled a lot better than what I'm doing currently.</s>

To think I've come so far... just a mere 2.5 years ago I was still a complete noob at Desmos golfing. Now, coming back to this answer 2.5 years later, there are so many golfs that I can spot. Shifting the bounds to remove the curly brackets, better ways to deal with the `n=1` edge case, and some other tiny golfs, resulted in an over 50% reduction in my original code. Truly amazing stuff.

#### Explanation

I will explain each sub-expression a little out of order from the actual code, but I feel that this is the best way to understand what the code is doing.

`∑_{n=a}^b`: Summation from `n=a` to `b`. This will iterate through all integers between `a` and `b` inclusive.

`∏_{k=3}^nmod(n,k-1)`: This takes the product of `k=3` to `n` of `mod(n,k-1)`which essentially tests all the possible divisors between `k=2` and `n-1`, and checks if `n` is divisible by `k` with `mod(n,k)` (it is `mod(n,k-1)` in the actual product, which will be explained further below). If `n` is composite then at least one value of `k` will make the `mod` expression equal to `0`, making the entire product equal to `0`. Otherwise, if `n` is a prime, then the product would be a positive integer. The reason why the product goes from `k=3` to `n` instead of the more intuitive `k=2` to `n-1` is because if the upper bound is represented by more than one character, then curly brackets are required to group the characters together. In other words, a product from `k=2` to `n-1` would be `∏_{k=2}^{n-1}`, which is four more bytes than `∏_{k=3}^n`. But because we have shifted the bounds of the product up by one, we will need to subtract one from all instances of `k` in order to compensate for the shift. Hence, we have `k-1` instead of `k` in the `mod` expression. This adds two bytes to our total code length, resulting in a net -2 bytes from doing this bound shifting. Now, because the bounds start from `k=3`, what happens if `n=1` or `2`? When the upper bound is lower than the lower bound, then the product will default to a value of `1`. This is an issue for the `n=1` case, which will result in the product being a positive integer (specifically `1`), but that is undesirable because a positive integer implies that `n=1` is a prime when in reality it isn't a prime. But there is a way to easily fix this...

`(n-1)`: This expression is solely to deal with the `n=1` case. When `n=1`, `n-1` is `0` which causes the entire product to equal `0`. For any other positive value, `n-1` would simply be a positive integer and not affect the overall sign of the product. Note that this fix only works for testing primality for positive integers, but this is okay for our code because the problem specifies that `a` and `b` can be assumed to be at least `1`. To deal with the `n=0` case as well, something like `0^{0^{n-1}}` would probably work.

`nsgn( ... )`: This takes `n` and multiplies it by the sign (`sgn` in the code) of the entire product expression. Remember that if the inside expression is a positive integer, then it is a prime; otherwise, it is composite. By taking the sign of the resulting integer, we will get `1` if `n` is prime and `0` if `n` is composite. Multiplying that by `n` will give `n` and `0` for the respective possibilities.

Now considering that we are taking a summation from `n=a` to `b`, this will essentially add `n` to the total sum if `n` is a prime, but it won't contribute to the sum if `n` is a composite. In other words, it takes the sum of all integers between `n=a` and `b` which are prime. With that, we are done.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes math.unicode`, <s>32</s> 23 bytes

```
[ primes-between Σ . ]
```

*-9 bytes* thanks to [chunes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97916/chunes)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXUJSZm1oMYZfmZSbnp6QqFBSllpRUAmXyShSs/0crQNToJqWWlKem5imcW6ygpxD730jBnKsgMzlbITkxJ4crOSc1seg/AA)

Comment: `prime?` and `Σ` are not available by default, so you need to change the header to "Factor + `math.primes math.unicode`" like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220659/78410).

Comment: Thank you, @Bubbler I changed the header of my answers :)

Comment: `primes-between` is shorter than `[a,b] [ prime? ] filter`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
IœP
```

##### Explanation

```python
IœP  # Implicit input
I    # Inclusive range, [a..b]
 œ   # Filtered by:
  P  #  Primality
     # Implicit output of sum (S flag)
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 103 chars

```
while(<>){($a,$b)=split/ /;for($a..$b){next if$_==1;for$n(2..$_-1){$_=0if$_%$n==0}$t+=$_;}print"$t\n";}
```

It'll accept multiple space separated lines and give the answer for each :D

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3: 99 chars**

```
l,h=map(int,input().split())
print(sum(p for p in range(l,h+1) if all(p%i for i in range(2,p)))-1)
```

Comment: This is not inclusive.

Comment: As noted by jamylak, this is not an inclusive range (try inputs `2 23`), and is therefore invalid per the challenge spec. As so, I’ve flagged your answer for deletion.

Comment: I am removing this answer as per our [policy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8076/68942) on handling [invalid submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/68942). Please feel free to edit this solution so it's valid and flag it for undeletion.

Comment: Whoever reflagged this for deletion, it was undeleted after being edited. I'm marking as "Looks OK", let me know if it's still invalid.

Answer (score 1):

### *Mathematica*, 27

Predefined `a` and `b`:

```
a~Range~b~Select~PrimeQ//Tr
```

As a function (also 27):

```
Tr[Range@##~Select~PrimeQ]&
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3: 86 chars

```python
a,b=map(int,input().split())
P=k=1
s=0
while k<=b:s+=P%k*k*(k>=a);P*=k*k;k+=1
print(s)
```

Uses the [factorial trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/20260) with [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem) to check whether `k` is prime. `P%k` is `1` if `k` is prime and `0` otherwise. If it is prime, `k` is added to the running sum `s`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 194

File fsoe-sum.py:

```
S,E=input()
L={}
n=2
s=0
while n<=E:
        try:
                P=L[n];del L[n]
        except:
                P=[n]
                if S<=n: s+=n
        for p in P:
                m=n+p
                try:
                        if p not in L[m]:L[m].append(p)
                except:
                        L[m] = [p]
        n+=1
print s
```

Filesize is 194 bytes when using tabs to indent and no final newline.

Not the shortest pythonish solution but do you see the enbedded sieve? ;-)

Run:

```
$ python fsoe-sum.py
1,1000000
37550402023
$ python fsoe-sum.py
1,2000000
142913828922
$ python fsoe-sum.py
1000001,2000000            
105363426899
$ python -c 'print 142913828922-37550402023'
105363426899
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 94

```
my$s;map{my($a,$b)=($_,0);for(2..$a-1){$a%$_==0&&$b++}$b or$s+=$a}($ARGV[0]..$ARGV[1]);print$s
```

This takes input from the command line. It doesn't use regex.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```
~,>{:x,{)x\%!},,2=},{+}*
```

This is based off of @w0lf's [prime number algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5987/41711).

Comment: Could you please add a "how it works"?

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
a!b=sum[x|x<-[a..b],all((<)0.mod x)[2..x-1]]
```

SEJPM helped me save 3 bytes!

Comment: 44 bytes: `a!b=sum[x|x<-[a..b],all((<)0.mod x)[2..x-1]]` (using `all` instead of `and`)

Comment: Fails for `1!3` (gives 6 instead of 5)..

Comment: a?b=sum[n|n<-[a..b],n>1,all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]], works for 1?3

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 60 bytes

```
require'prime';p=->a,b{eval Prime.each(b).reject{|x|x<a}*?+}
```

### Usage

```
puts p[*gets.split.map(&:to_i)]
```

#### Inputs & Outputs

```
2 10     #=> 10
3 10     #=> 8
100 1000 #=> 75067
```

Answer (score 1):

## Casio-Basic, 42 bytes

```
sum(seq(piecewise(isPrime(x),x,0),x,a,b
```

Uses a hybrid/piecewise function that returns the number if it's prime, otherwise return 0. `seq` runs this over the range a to b, then `sum` adds it all up.

39 bytes for the function, 3 bytes to enter `a,b` as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 10 bytes

```
L,d@ßrÞP¦+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJ8Xh8Pyiw/MCDi3T/v//v9F/I@N/@QUlmfl5xf91dTNzC3IykzNLAA)

### How it works

```
D,f,@@,		; Define a dyadic function, f
		; Example arguments:	[2 23]
	d	; Duplicate;	STACK = [2 23 23]
	@	; Reverse;	STACK = [23 23 2]
	ßr	; Range;	STACK = [23 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22]
	Þ	; Filter on:
	  P	;  Primality	STACK = [23 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19]
	¦+	; Sum;		STACK = [100]
		; Implicitly return top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 11 chars, 22 bytes

```
{+/⍵/⍨0π¨⍵}
```

test one range:

```
{+/⍵/⍨0π¨⍵}  1..23
  100
{+/⍵/⍨0π¨⍵}  1..22
  77
{+/⍵/⍨0π¨⍵}1..1
  0
```

test two ranges:

```
{+/⍵/⍨0π¨⍵}¨(1..22)(1..23)
  77 100
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3: 259 characters**
This is a longer solution, but it's more efficient than the one-liner I first posted.

```
import itertools as i
l,h=map(int,input().split())
F=lambda p:lambda x:x%p
def S(s):
 while 1:
  yield (p:=next(s),s:=filter(F(p),s) if p*p<=h else s)[0]
P=lambda:(yield from S(i.count(2)))
print(sum(i.takewhile(lambda e:e<=h,i.dropwhile(lambda e:e<l,P()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 69 bytes

```
> Input
> Input
>> 1…2
>> L’
>> Select∧ 4 3
>> ∑5
>> Output 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hAtO2ykYPmpYZgRi@DxqmAmig1NzUpNLHnUsVzBRMAYJPOqYaAqi/UtLgHoUzP7/N@IyBwA)

simply makes an inclusive range and filters it, then sums it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2), 82 bytes

```py
for i in range(input(),input()+1):P=n=1;exec'P*=n*n;n+=1;'*~-i;exec P%n*'print;'*i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VIzOvoLREQ1MHSmsbaloF2ObZGlqnVqQmqwdo2eZp5VnnaQMF1LXqdDPBwgoBqnla6gVFmXklQNHM//8NuQwNDAA) Outputs in unary using a newline as a tally mark.

```py
for i in range(input(),input()+1):P=n=1;exec'...'*~-i;exec P%n*'...'*i  # trimmed program
for   in                         :     ;             ;                  # for... 
    i                                                                   # variable...
for   in                         :     ;             ;                  # in...
         range(       ,         )                                       # [...
               input()                                                  # input...
         range(                 )                                       # , ...,
                       input()                                          # input...
                              +                                         # plus...
                               1                                        # literal...
         range(                 )                                       # ]...
                                     =                                  # set...
                                    n                                   # variable...
                                     =                                  # to...
                                      1                                 # literal
                                   =                                    # set...
                                  P                                     # variable...
                                   =                                    # to...
                                    n                                   # variable
                                        exec                            # execute...
                                            '...'                       # literal...
                                                 *                      # repeated...
                                                  ~                     # negative...
                                                   -                    # negative...
                                                    i                   # variable...
                                                  ~                     # minus 1...
                                                 *                      # times...
                                        exec                            # as Python code
                                                      exec              # execute...
                                                               '...'    # literal...
                                                              *         # repeated...
                                                           P            # variable...
                                                            %           # modulo...
                                                             n          # variable...
                                                              *         # times...
                                                                    *   # repeated...
                                                                     i  # variable...
                                                                    *   # times...
                                                      exec              # as Python code

====================

P*=n*n;n+=1;  # full program
 *=           # set...
P             # variable...
 *=           # to...
P             # variable...
 *=           # multiplied by...
   n          # variable...
    *         # multiplied by...
     n        # variable
        +=    # set...
       n      # variable...
        +=    # to...
          1   # literal...
        +=    # added to...
       n      # variable

====================

print;  # full program
print   # output nothing with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes`, 37 bytes

```
: f ( x y -- n ) primes-between sum ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYsxDoMwEAT7vGLLUJiCdOYBEQ0NygMIWgQKPsA@BLzeWKFZjUazfdvp7OOnqeq3xY9eOMG1OvwnX/zoGBC4bpQu0eKpeiYtivJR1RbKoNGixxMHThgDQYb7aL7UnRSEzaGMBYpXCvN4AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
⟦₂ṗˢ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@amh7unH56kfb//9FGOoYGBrH/owA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦₂       Range from the 2 numbers in the Input
  ṗˢ     Select all primes
    +    Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
1+:gNkS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLDbWt0v2ygyE8qOCCJUbGXEYQNgA)

Takes \$ b \$ first, then \$ a \$

##### Explanation

```python
1+:gNkS  # Implicit input, b then a
1+       # Pop b and push b+1
  :      # Pop both and push [a..b+1)
   gNk   # Filter for primes only
      S  # Sum the resulting list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Φ└♪Y╓U↨M
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e8c00d59d655174d&i=2+23)

This is a packed stax program which unpacks to the following 10 bytes:

```
^|r{|p}f|+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5E%7Cr%7B%7Cp%7Df%7C%2B&i=2+23)

```
^|r{|p}f|+ # takes input a,b
^          # increment b
 |r        # range from a..b+1
   {  }f   # filter by
    |p     # is prime?
        |+ # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
),\>{mp},:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/V9TJ8auOregVsdK@3@tVYQ1l5KhjoKhgYGCrZ2CkiGYFcHlx6VkpKNgZAwWNAIxIv4DAA)

Essentially a port of my [Stax answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259180/114970)

## Explanation

```
),\>{mp},:+ # function taking a,b
)           # increment b
 ,          # range 0..b+1
  \         # swap to put a on top of stack
   >        # drop a elements from the range 0..b+1, essentially making it range(a,b+1)
    {  },   # filter by
     mp     # primality
         :+ # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```arturo
print∑select..loop arg=>do=>prime?
```

[image]

```
print         ; print
∑             ; sum
select        ; select certain items from a block
..            ; range
loop arg=>do  ; eval each command line argument and place on stack
=>prime?      ; are they prime? (select)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 20 bits<sup>1</sup>, 2.5 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
ṡ~æ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJzPSIsIiIsIuG5oX7DpiIsIiIsIjExXG4xMiJd)

Somehow, I never noticed the existing answer is actually invalid.

### Explained

```
ṡ~æ
ṡ    # Range [a, b]
 ~æ  # Filtered to only contain primes
# Summed by the s flag
```

Answer (score 1):

## SAS, 163 bytes

I got suggestion that use of macro variables for input is "invalid method", here is other version of the code which basically wraps the original one (look below) inside a `%window` statement (makes it more obfuscated and limits it use to the DMS env. only):

The prompt window for DMS:

```
%window i a 4 b 4;%display i;
```

The code that sums primes and prints result to the log

```
data;array a[&b](. 2:&b);do i=2 to sqrt(&b);if a[i] then do j=2*a[i] by a[i] while(j<=&b);a[j]=.;end;end;x=sum(of a&a--a&b);put x;run;
```

Length of the code which "does the job" effectively stays the same.

Let me share a comment about "invalidity" of the first approach:

Passing input data in all 3 programming interfaces SAS DMS, SAS EG, or SAS Studio can be done:

1. by a SAS dataset,
2. by a text file,
3. hard-coded inside data step, and
4. by macrovariables.

A programmer does not have to wrap-up 4GL code inside a macro to use macrovariables in it, for example the following works perfectly well:

```
%let a=42;

data _null_;
  the_answer=&a.;
  put the_answer;
run;
```

The DMS allows `window` and `display` statements and they macro language counterparts `%window` and `%display` to produce a prompt input window. Unfortunately those are DMS "specific" and not working in the EG or SAS Studio interfaces.

Assuming we are working in the DMS env. For a SAS programmer execution of the following code, which creates and opens prompt input window:

```
%window in
@1 'a:' a 8 'b:' b 8;
%display in;
```

just before the data step and typing in values of a and b

is effectively equivalent to running:

```
%let a=XXX;
%let b=YYY;
```

with `XXX` and `YYY` as values for a and b.

---

- The original post below:*

input in SAS can be done by macrovariables:

```
%let a=3;
%let b=1000000;
```

the code sums primes and prints result to the log

```
data;array a[&b](. 2:&b);do i=2 to sqrt(&b);if a[i] then do j=2*a[i] by a[i] while(j<=&b);a[j]=.;end;end;x=sum(of a&a--a&b);put x;run;
```

more readable version, `_null_` added to stop dataset creation:

```
%let a=3;
%let b=1000000;
data ;
  array a[&b] (. 2:&b); /* array of integers from 2 to b */
  do i = 2 to sqrt(&b); /* loop until sqrt of b */
    if a[i] then        /* if there is value in the array at i */
      do j=2*a[i] by a[i] while (j<=&b);
        a[j] = .;       /* ... replace all multiplicities of a[i] with missings */
      end;
  end;
  x = sum(of a&a--a&b); /* sum elements for position a to b */
  put x;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

## SAS, 130 <s>134</s>

I got suggestion that use of macro variables for input is "invalid method", here is other version of the code which basically wraps the original one (look below) inside a `%window` statement (makes it more obfuscated and limits it use to the DMS env. only):

The prompt window for DMS:

```
%window i a 4 b 4;%display i;
```

[Edit: some spaces were not necessary.]
The code that sums primes and prints result to the log

```
data;array a[&b](. 2:&b);do i=2to sqrt(&b);if a[i]then do j=2*a[i]by a[i]while(j<=&b);a[j]=.;end;end;x=sum(of a&a--a&b);put x;run;
```

Length of the code which "does the job" effectively stays the same.

Let me share a comment about "invalidity" of the first approach:

Passing input data in all 3 programming interfaces SAS DMS, SAS EG, or SAS Studio can be done:

1. by a SAS dataset,
2. by a text file,
3. hard-coded inside data step, and
4. by macrovariables.

A programmer does not have to wrap-up 4GL code inside a macro to use macrovariables in it, for example the following works perfectly well:

```
%let a=42;

data _null_;
  the_answer=&a.;
  put the_answer;
run;
```

The DMS allows `window` and `display` statements and they macro language counterparts `%window` and `%display` to produce a prompt input window. Unfortunately those are DMS "specific" and not working in the EG or SAS Studio interfaces.

Assuming we are working in the DMS env. For a SAS programmer execution of the following code, which creates and opens prompt input window:

```
%window in
@1 'a:' a 8 'b:' b 8;
%display in;
```

just before the data step and typing in values of a and b

is effectively equivalent to running:

```
%let a=XXX;
%let b=YYY;
```

with `XXX` and `YYY` as values for a and b.

---

*The original post below:*

input in SAS can be done by macrovariables:

```
%let a=3;
%let b=1000000;
```

the code sums primes and prints result to the log

```
data;array a[&b](. 2:&b);do i=2 to sqrt(&b);if a[i] then do j=2*a[i] by a[i] while(j<=&b);a[j]=.;end;end;x=sum(of a&a--a&b);put x;run;
```

more readable version, `_null_` added to stop dataset creation:

```
%let a=3;
%let b=1000000;
data ;
  array a[&b] (. 2:&b); /* array of integers from 2 to b */
  do i = 2 to sqrt(&b); /* loop until sqrt of b */
    if a[i] then        /* if there is value in the array at i */
      do j=2*a[i] by a[i] while (j<=&b);
        a[j] = .;       /* ... replace all multiplicities of a[i] with missings */
      end;
  end;
  x = sum(of a&a--a&b); /* sum elements for position a to b */
  put x;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 260 bytes

```
object P extends App{
def c(M:Int)={val p=(false::false::true::List.range(3,M+1).map(_%2!=0)).toArray
for(i<-(3 to M)
if p(i))
{var j=i*i
while(j<M){p(j)=false
j+=i}}
p}
val l=args.map(_.toInt)
val p=c(l(1))
println((l(0)to l(1)).filter(p).map(_.toLong).sum)}
```

A self-written primes-sieve.

```
time scala P 3900000 4000000
25811704341

real    0m8.288s
user    0m6.968s
sys 0m0.456s
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 133

A little bit of sorcery:

```
x,y=map(int,raw_input().split())
y+=1
a=range(y)
print sum(i for i in[[i for a[::i]in[([0]*y)[::i]]][0]for i in a[2:]if a[i]]if i>=x)
```

Comment: You can remove `y+=1` and instead use `range(y+1)` and `([0]*-~y)[::i]` to save a byte (removing the newline). And using Python 3 will allow you to use `input()`, as long as you put parentheses after `print`, therefore removing 4 bytes, but adding 1. Worth it.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 94 bytes

```
$a,$b=$args[0,1]
(.{$p=2..$b
while($p){$p[0];$p=@($p|?{$_%$p[0]})}}|
?{$_-gt$a}|
measure -s).sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## F# (141)

One third of the code is for parsing the input.

```
let[|a;b|]=System.Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')
{int a..int b}|>Seq.filter(fun n->n>1&&Seq.forall((%)n>>(<>)0){2..n-1})|>Seq.sum|>printfn"%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 62 with bonus

```
use ntheory":all";while(<>){say vecsum(@{primes(split/\s+/)})}
```

Takes lines with two whitespace separated numbers and prints the sum of primes within the range.  Exits when it sees EOF.

47 for the simple case we assume the input magically arrives in $a and $b like a few other solutions:

```
use ntheory":all";forprimes{$s+=$_}$a,$b;say$s
```

or

```
use ntheory":all";say vecsum(@{primes($a,$b)})
```

With a newer module version that can be 39 characters:

```
use ntheory":all";say sum_primes($a,$b)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 69 bytes

```matlab
a,b=int(split(readline()));println(sum(setdiff(primes(b),primes(a))))
```

This reads a space-delimited pair of integers from STDIN and prints the result to STDOUT. The only thing I've really golfed here is whitespace; otherwise this is probably how I would go about it in a non-golfing context.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
# Read a line from STDIN, split it into an array on the space, convert
# the elements to integers, and assign the first element to a and the
# second to b
a, b = int(split(readline()))

# Get the primes between a and b inclusive. primes(x) returns the primes
# <= x, so the set difference of primes(b) and primes(a) will get us only
# those between a and b
d = setdiff(primes(b), primes(a))

# Print the sum to STDOUT
println(sum(d))
```

Just realized how old this challenge is.

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org), 103 bytes

```rkt
(define(s a b)(for/sum([n(range a(+ b 1))]#:when(and(> n 1)(=(modulo(apply *(range 1 n))n)(- n 1))))n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NCsJADIRfJdDLRBFZwYugLyI9pG6q4jZbUov49OuqPc0P3zAul4c@S5PEruT/gKj93RQTCXWMPvt2mgecDV4pJcGaOgrMbXN43dQgFnEiqxWOGHKcU4aMY3rTapkEMmZjbH4Ufz2XegBXibwIl0C7/Qc)

---

### Explanation

This function receives two range inputs: \$ 1 \le a \le b \text{ (inclusive)} \$. It returns the sum of all prime numbers between the range. To determine whether `n` is a prime number or not, two conditions must be satisfied:

The first condition is \$ n > 1 \$ as 1 is not a prime. The second condition is the observation that [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) returns \$ n - 1 \$ when \$n\$ is a prime.

$$ n - 1 = (n - 1)!\mod n $$

| n | \$(n - 1)! \mod n \$ | Is a prime? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | Yes |
| 3 | 2 | Yes |
| 4 | 2 | No |
| 5 | 4 | Yes |
| 6 | 0 | No |

The reason for the first condition is that the theorem states that 1 is a prime, but it isn't. The theorem is only accurate when \$ n \ge 2 \$.

Putting this into the code is simple:

```rkt
(define (sum-of-primes a b)
  (for/sum ([n (range a (+ b 1))]
            #:when (and (> n 1)
                        (= (modulo (apply * (range 1 n)) n)
                           (- n 1))))
    n))  ; will be collected
```

The [`for/sum`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fsum%29%29) loop collects all the values when `#;when` is true. So if the number is a prime number, `for/sum` will add it. Once the loop has finished iterating, it will return the summed up result.

Have a wonderful weekend!