# Find sum of odd numbers

Tags: code-golf, restricted-time

Write a program to find the sum of all odd numbers between a given range [a,b]. Input consists of a single line containing two integers a and b separated by a space. 0 ≤ a,b ≤ 1,000,000,000,000. Your program should not take more than 10 secs.

```
Sample Inputs
1 5
4 8
1 8
0 5

Sample Outputs
9
12
16
9
```

Comment: *sigh* ... ... ...

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of [Sum of primes between given range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/113). The fundamental challenge is the same (generate a range from \$a\$ to \$b\$, filter elements that meet a criteria, then sum), and, in my opinion, the two are the same task

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing I strongly disagree. Brute force is not allowed in this challenge because of the time limit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Ruby, 43 characters

```
p eval"-(%d/2)**2+((%d+1)/2)**2"%gets.split
```

Example for largest input:

```
$ time echo "1 10000000000000000" | ruby oddsum.rb
25000000000000000000000000000000

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: You misspelled *evil* there. Otherwise, nice work!

Comment: You can replace `(%d+1)` with just `-%d` to save 3 bytes

Answer (score 14):

### [Funciton](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Funciton)

Not a language particularly suitable for golfing, but I gave it my best shot to cram everything together in best code-golf tradition. Near the end I was making rearrangements that gave net savings of a single character until I could find no more ways to improve it :)

This is **398 characters** (or 786 bytes in UTF-16). I challenge anyone to find a way to make it smaller :)

```
 ┌───┐    ┌──────────┐
╔╧╗┌─┴╖┌─╖│╔═╗┌──╖┌─╖│
║ ║│>>╟┤_╟┘║1╟┤>>╟┤♯╟┘
╚═╝╘╤═╝╘═╝ ╚═╝╘═╤╝╘═╝
    └┐ ┌─┐ ╔══╗┌┴───┐
╔══╗┌┴╖│┌┴╖║32║│ ┌─╖│
║21╟┤×╟┘│♯║╚╤═╝└─┤×╟┘
╚══╝╘═╝ ╘╤╝┌┘ ┌─┐╘╤╝
┌──────┬─┘┌┘ ┌┴╖└─┘
│╔═╗  ┌┴╖┌┘  │−╟┐┌───────╖
│║0║ ┌┤ʘ╟┘┌─┐╘╤╝└┤int→str╟
│╚╤╝ │╘═╝┌┴╖└─┘  ╘═══════╝
│┌┴╖╔╧╗┌─┤×╟┐
└┤ʃ╟╢ ║│ ╘═╝│
 ╘╤╝╚═╝└┬───┘
  │┌─╖┌─┴╖╔═╗╓─╖┌───────╖
  └┤_╟┤>>╟╢1║║_╟┤str→int╟
   ╘═╝╘══╝╚═╝╙─╜╘═══════╝
```

Comment: What about BOCU-1 or SCSU? Wouldn't those make it quite a bit smaller?

Comment: @Joey: Certainly not the character count.

Comment: Ah, but the byte count ;-). Ok, I only now understood how you meant that.

Answer (score 4):

### Windows PowerShell, <s>84</s> <s>61</s> 55

```
$a,$b=-split"$input+1"|iex|%{($_-band-2)/2}
$b*$b-$a*$a
```

O(1) runtime.

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript - 12 chars

```
~)2/2?\2/2?-
```

can be done in 11 chars if the order of the inputs is reversed

```
~)]{2/2?}/-
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 32 bytes

As unnamed lambda function:

```python
lambda a,b:((b+1)/2)**2-(a/2)**2
```

Did some math to get a direct formula. Proof will follow.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 7 bytes

```
›"2ḭ²Ḃ¯
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E2%80%BA%222%E1%B8%AD%C2%B2%E1%B8%82%C2%AF&inputs=8%0A4&header=&footer=)

```
STACK = [4,8]
›               Increment, [5, 8]
"               Pair  [[5, 8]]
2              Push 2 [[5, 8], 2]
ḭ               Integer Division [[2, 4]]
²               Square [[4, 16]]
Ḃ              Reverse [[16, 4]]
¯               Deltas    [[12]]
                 Implicit Sum [12]
```

Comment: Does not work within the time limit.

Comment: @Bubbler edited

Comment: this doesn't meet the problems I/O requirements (which are overly strict but you still must follow them)

Comment: I see that Vyxal has commands for split on spaces, convert string to int, and mapping functions, so I'm sure there's some way to combine those to fulfill the requirements