# Evaluate the primorial of a number

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, number-theory, primes

The primorial of a number is the product of all the primes until that number, itself included.

Take a number from `STDIN` as the input and evaluate its primorial, also known as the prime factorial.

Don't use libraries. Shortest code wins.

**Test cases:**

```
1 1
2 2
3 6
4 6
5 30
6 30
7 210
8 210
9 210
10 210
11 2310
12 2310
13 30030
14 30030
15 30030
16 30030
17 510510
18 510510
19 9699690
```

Comment: Essentially the same task as [Sum of primes between given range](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113/sum-of-primes-between-given-range), just with multiplication instead of addition and the starting value of the range is fixed.

Comment: As demonstrated below: multiplication is very different from summation, especially for primes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### J, 13 characters

```
*/p:i._1 p:1+
```

Examples:

```
   */p:i._1 p:1+7
210

   */p:i._1 p:1+12
2310
```

Comment: Damn. Just beat me.

Comment: Did I just see an instance of telepathy?!

Comment: @SohamChowdhury, no, you saw an instance of a trivial answer to a trivial question.

Comment: Boohoo you just trolled me.

Comment: Does J have a built-in way of calculating primes?

Comment: @arshajii See, e.g. [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dpco.htm).

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, 49 bytes

```python
P=k=1
exec"P*=P**k%k<1or k;k+=1;"*input()
print P
```

Counts up `k` from 1 to the input, updating the primorial `P` by multiplying `P` by `k` whenever it's prime. Since `P` contains all lower prime factors, a sufficiently high power of `P` will contain `k` as a factor if and only if `k` is non-prime. The power `P**k` suffices, and we check whether `P**k%k<1`, multipling `P` by 1 if so (doing nothing) and by `k` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 21

The large Pi represents the product function.

`PrimePi@n` returns the number of primes up to and including n.

`Prime@i` returns the ith prime.

[image: product2]

Comment: C'mon... the product function is one char?! That's an ingenious workaround!

Comment: Thanks. It's somewhat like the case of "a+b", which is shorthand for Plus[a,b] or "a.b.c", which stands for the dot product, Dot[a,b,c].

Answer (score 4):

## PARI/GP, 22 bytes

```
prodeuler(x=1,input,x)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Python, 72 characters

Quickly golfed, I imagine there are better python solutions.

```
n=t=1;exec"t*=(1,n)[all(n%i for i in range(2,n))];n+=1;"*input();print t
```

I used [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) to verify up to 71

Usage:

```
$ python primorial.py
100
2305567963945518424753102147331756070

$ python primorial.py
101
232862364358497360900063316880507363070
```

Comment: Whoops, just updated it so it actually works!

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 27 chars

```
Times@@Prime@Range@PrimePi@
```

Usage

```
Times@@Prime@Range@PrimePi@100
(*
2305567963945518424753102147331756070
*)
```

Comment: I counted only 27 chars.

Comment: @DavidCarraher You're right. Thanks

Comment: Is that `@` symbol at the end meant to be there? On it's own that'd be invalid syntax. You could probably just omit it.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 125 bytes

```
p(n,x){return x==1?n:n%x?p(n,x-1):1;}
f(n){return n==1?1:p(n,n-1)*f(n-1);}
main(){int n;scanf("%d",&n);printf("%d\n",f(n));}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 90 chars

```
main=getLine>>= \v->print.product.takeWhile(<=read v)$[n|n<-[2..],all((>0).rem n)[2..n-1]]
```

or (also 90 chars):

```
main=getLine>>=print.product.flip takeWhile [n|n<-[2..],all((>0).rem n)[2..n-1]].(>=).read
```

#### Compilation

```
ghc primorial.hs
```

#### Usage

```
$ echo "12" | ./primorial
2310
```

or

```
$ ./primorial
12<ENTER>
2310
```

Comment: Some room for improvement here. `takeWhile` is unnecessary, we can just add an upper limit for the `[2..]` instead. Instead of `getLine` + `read`, we can use `readLn`. Also, `do`-notation is slightly shorter than using `>>=`. Result: `main=do v<-readLn;print$product[n|n<-[2..v],all((>0).rem n)[2..n-1]]` (68 characters)

Answer (score 1):

### R - 48

```
x=1:scan();prod(x[rowSums(outer(x,x,`%%`)<1)<3])
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/Octave, 23 bytes

```
prod(primes(input('')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/oCg/RaOgKDM3tVgjM6@gtERDXV1TU/P/f3MA)

Answer (score 1):

## Casio-Basic, 41 bytes

```
prod(seq(piecewise(isPrime(x),x,1),x,1,n
```

Since the calculator doesn't have a "select" function of any kind, a piecewise/hybrid function is used to return the number if it's prime, otherwise return 1. `seq` does this over a range of integers from 1 to n, and `prod` multiplies the whole list together.

40 bytes for the function, +1 byte to enter `n` in the parameters box.

Answer (score 0):

**Smalltalk**, Squeak 4.x flavour

Let's say we read n from stdin in 38 chars (this kind of requirement is just killing!)

```
n:=FileStream stdin nextLine asNumber.
```

If only product were defined in Collection in base image, this could be as simple as

```
^(0class primesUpTo:n+1)product
```

or:

```
^((2to:n)select:#isPrime)product
```

Unfortunately, we have to code #product by ourself in 48 chars (**86** total).

```
(0class primesUpTo:n+1)inject:1into:[:p :i|p*i]
```

Or if primesUpTo: is considered as a library, we can use isPrime in 62 chars (**100** total)

```
^(1to:n)inject:1into:[:p :i|i isPrime ifTrue:[p*i]ifFalse:[p]]
```

If even isPrime is forbidden we can find by ourselves in 67 chars (**105** total)

```
p:=1. 2to:n do:[:i|((2to:i-1)anySatisfy:[:d|i\\d=0])or:[p:=p*i]].^p
```

Or for the fun, we can use a sieve in 108 chars (**146** total)

```
s:=(p:=y:=1)<<n-2. 2to:n do:[:x|y:=(z:=y)*2+1.(z+1bitAnd:s)=0or:[p:=p*x.s:=z<<(n//x*x+x)//y+z+1bitAnd:s]].^p
```

Explanation of the sieve at http://smallissimo.blogspot.fr/2011/07/revisiting-sieve-of-erathostenes.html

Nota: bitAnd: has a short-cut operator & in Pharo 2.0, which would reduce Sieve cost to 94 chars (**132** total)

```
s:=(p:=y:=1)<<n-2. 2to:n do:[:x|y:=(z:=y)*2+1.z+1&s=0or:[p:=p*x.s:=z<<(n//x*x+x)//y+z+1&s]].^p
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 76 bytes

```
main=interact$ \n->show$product[x|x<-[2..read n],and[x`mod`y>0|y<-[2..x-1]]]
```

Example:

```
$ echo 12 | ./primorial
2310
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 213 bytes

```
class M{public static void main(String[]a){c(new Long(a[0]));}static void c(long n){long r=1,i=0;for(;++i<=n;r*=p(i)?i:1);System.out.print(r);}static boolean p(long n){int i=2;while(i<n)n=n%i++<1?0:n;return n>1;}}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
class M{
  static void c(long n){
    long r = 1,
         i = 0;
    for (; ++i <= n; r *= p(i) ? i : 1);
    System.out.print(r);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    c(new Long(a[0]));
  }

  static boolean p(long n){
    int i = 2;
    while(i < n){
      n = n % i++ < 1 ? 0 : n;
    }
    return n > 1;
  }
}
```

**Usage:** `java -jar M.jar 17`
**Output:** `510510`

Comment: Anything after Java SE 7 Update 21 is disallowed for being released after the challenge was created. Make sure what you use is from that update or before. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ÆRP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW1DA////zQE)

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 6 bytes

```
S²P¬-*
```

### Explained

```
S²P¬-*
S       # Produce as stack from 1 to the input.
 ²  -   # Filter it by the function provided
  P¬    # Is it not a prime?
     *  # Get the product of the now list of primes.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z/40KaAQ2t0tf7//29oAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 6 bytes

```
õ fj ×
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SBmaiDX&input=OA==)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ÅPP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cGtAwP//hpYA)