# Prime Factorial

Tags: code-golf, math, number, primes

For the purposes of this question, the prime factorial of a number n is the result of multiplying all prime numbers smaller than n, and then multiplying the result by n.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function to find the prime factorial of a number, as outlined above.

### Input:

An integer n where n is greater than one, and the prime factorial of n is smaller than the largest integer your language can support.  However, remember [this standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/69331).  Reasonable integer limits only.

### Output:

The prime factorial of the input.

### Test Cases:

```
4  -> 24
7  -> 210
32 -> 641795684160
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: No way we haven't had this challenge before...

Comment: @xnor [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11719/71256)?

Comment: I didn't think of searching for "primorial" when I was dupe-checking.  Sandbox didn't catch it either.

Comment: @Gryphon Yeah, it's strange that "prime factorial" doesn't appear on that challenge. I edited it to make it a bit more searchable.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought it was weird we hadn't already had something like this, but I couldn't find anything, so I posted in the sandbox, which also didn't find anything.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted please tell me why.  I like to know why my posts are being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
’ÆRP×
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zDbUEBh6f////fHAA)**

### How?

```
’ÆRP×   Full program.

’       Decrement.
 ÆR     Inclusive prime range.
   P    Product.
    ×   Multiply by the input.
```

The non-built-in would be **7 bytes**: `’ÆPÐfP×`

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
*Q*FfP_TSt
```

I'm pretty sure this can be golfed some more...

---

```
*Q*FfP_TSt     Full program, takes input from stdin and outputs to stdout
*Q             Implicitly output $input multiplied by 
  *F           The product of
        St(Q)  All numbers less than $input (Q is added automtaically by Pyth)
    fP_T       As long as they are prime
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can omit the `Q`

Comment: Can you replace `St` with `U`?

Comment: 8 bytes: `**FfP_TU` or `*F+fP_TU`

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB/Octave, 23 bytes

```
@(n)prod(primes(n-1))*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mG/PfQSNPs6AoP0WjoCgzN7VYI0/XUFNTK@9/moaJJleahjmIMDbS/A8A)

Comment: Mobile bug.. >_>