# Do I have a prime twin?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, primes

An Integer is *prime* if and only if it is positive and has exactly 2 distinct divisors: 1 and itself. A twin prime pair is made of two elements: `p` and `p±2`, that are both prime.

You will be given a positive integer as input. Your task is to return a truthy / falsy depending on whether the given integer belongs to a twin pair, following the standard [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules (the values need to be consistent).

### Test Cases

- Truthy (Twin Primes): `3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 29, 31, 41, 43`
- Falsy (not Twin Primes): `2, 15, 20, 23, 37, 47, 97, 120, 566`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: is 13 a prime twin?

Comment: @LiefdeWen Yes, because it belongs to the pair (11, 13)

Comment: This is [OEIS A001097](https://oeis.org/A001097).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ṗ∧4√;?+ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@HO6Y86lps86phlba8N5Pz/b2T5HwA)

#### Explanation

```
ṗ           Input is prime
 ∧          And
  4√        A number whose square is 4 (i.e. -2 or 2)
    ;?+     That number + the Input…
       ṗ    …is prime
```

Comment: Beating Jelly and tying 05AB1E, nice

Comment: Clever `√` usage! +1

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
%6+_2_ÆP⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/VTDveKP5wW8Cjxl3/DQ0MD7cfnpDmrfBwx/ZHDXMUQsoz8xQKijJzU4sVSgsUSvIVgEr0/gMA)

#### Background

With the exception of **(3, 5)**, all twin prime pairs are of the form **(6k - 1, 6k + 1)**.

Since **(6k - 1) + (6k - 1) % 6 - 3 = 6k - 1 + 5 - 3 = 6k + 1** and
**(6k + 1) + (6k + 1) % 6 - 3 = 6k + 1 + 1 - 3 = 6k - 1**, given an input **n > 3**, it is sufficient to check whether **n** and **n + n % 6 - 3** are both prime.

This formula *happens to* work for **n = 3** as well, as **3 + 3 % 6 - 3 = 3** is prime and **3** is a twin prime.

#### How it works

```
%6+_2_ÆP⁺  Main link. Argument: n

%6         Compute n%6.
  +        Add n to the result.
   _2      Subtract 2.
     _ÆP   Subtract 1 if n is prime, 0 if not.
           If n is not a prime, since (n + n%6 - 2) is always even, this can only
           yield a prime if (n + n%6 - 2 = 2), which happens only when n = 2.
        ⁺  Call ÆP again, testing the result for primality.
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum((n+n%6-3)*n%k<1for k in range(2,4*n))==2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RckxDkAwGAbQmVP8i6SlhtIYRG9iqVAafKQYnL6YbC95@31OG8pgSVMbFrN2vSHUx7UyhgxJlZc8RTI30m6eZnIgbzAOrBAqBedaF@Eb/CMFVUrxOo6cJcvwKdq9w/k6PA)

#### Background

All integers take one of the following forms, with integer **k**: **6k - 3**, **6k - 2**, **6k - 1**, **6k**, **6k + 1**, **6k + 2**.

Since **6k - 2**, **6k**, and **6k + 2** are all even, and since **6k - 3** is divisible by **3**, all primes except **2** and **3** must be of the form **6k - 1** or **6k + 1**. Since the difference of a twin prime pair is **2**, with the exception of **(3, 5)**, all twin prime pairs are of the form **(6k - 1, 6k + 1)**.

Let **n** be of the form **6k ± 1**.

- If **n = 6k -1**, then **n + n%6 - 3 = 6k - 1 + (6k - 1)%6 - 3 = 6k - 1 + 5 - 3 = 6k + 1**.
- If **n = 6k + 1**, then **n + n%6 - 3 = 6k + 1 + (6k + 1)%6 - 3 = 6k + 1 + 1 - 3 = 6k - 1**.

Thus, *if* **n** is part of a twin prime pair and **n ≠ 3**, it's twin will be **n + n%6 - 3**.

#### How it works

Python doesn't have a built-in primality test. While there are short-ish ways to test a single number for primality, doing so for two number would be lengthy. We're going to work with divisors instead.

```python
sum((n+n%6-3)*n%k<1for k in range(2,4*n))
```

counts how many integers **k** in the interval **[2, 4n)** divide **(n + n%6 - 3)n** evenly, i.e., it counts the number of divisors of **(n + n%6 - 3)n** in the interval **[2, 4n)**.  We claim that this count is **2** if and only if **n** is part of a twin prime pair.

- If **n = 3** (a twin prime), **(n + n%6 - 3)n = 3(3 + 3 - 3) = 9** has two divisors (**3** and **9**) in **[2, 12)**.
- If **n > 3** is a twin prime, as seen before, **m := n + n%6 - 3** is its twin. In this case, **mn** has exactly four divisors: **1, m, n, mn**.

  Since **n > 3**, we have **m > 4**, so **4n < mn** and exactly two divisors (**m** and **n**) fall into the interval **[2, 4n)**.
- If **n = 1**, then **(n + n%6 - 3)n = 1 + 1 - 3 = -1** has no divisors in **[2, 4)**.
- If **n = 2**, then **(n + n%6 - 3)n = 2(2 + 2 - 3) = 2** has one divisor (itself) in **[2, 8)**.
- If **n = 4**, then **(n + n%6 - 3)n = 4(4 + 4 - 3) = 20** has four divisors (**2**, **4**, **5**, and **10**) in **[2, 16)**.
- If **n > 4** is even, **2**, **n/2**, and **n** all divide **n** and, therefore, **(n + n%6 - 3)n**. We have **n/2 > 2** since **n > 4**, so there are at least three divisors in **[2, 4n)**.
- If **n = 9**, then **(n + n%6 - 3)n = 9(9 + 3 - 3) = 81** has three divisors (**3**, **9**, and **21**) in **[2, 36)**.
- If **n > 9** is a multiple of **3**, then **3**, **n/3**, and **n** all divide **n** and, therefore, **(n + n%6 - 3)n**. We have **n/3 > 3** since **n > 9**, so there are at least three divisors in **[2, 4n)**.
- Finally, if **n = 6k ± 1 > 4** is not a twin prime, either **n** or **m := n + n%6 - 3** must be composite and, therefore, admit a proper divisor **d > 1**.

  Since either **n = m + 2** or **m = n + 2** and **n, m > 4**, the integers **d**, **m**, and **n** are *distinct* divisors of **mn**. Furthermore, **m < n + 3 < 4n** since **n > 1**, so **mn** has at least three divisors in **[2, 4n)**.

Comment: Wow. Such short code and yet so many special cases it must handle correctly. Any reason you say Python 3? As far as I can tell it also works in Python 2.

Comment: Yes, this will work just as well in Python 2. The **3** is part of the auto-generated SE post from TIO.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Datboi*

```
ÌIÍ‚pZIp*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cI/n4d5HDbMKojwLtP7/N7IEAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvn/cE/l4d5HDbMKoioLtP5XKh3eb6VweL@STsx/Yy5TLnMuQ0MuQ2MuQyDDksvIksvYkMsEiIy5jLgMTbmMDLiMjLmMzblMzLksgUqAfFMzMwA)

**Explanation**

```
Ì           # push input+2
 IÍ         # push input-2
   ‚        # pair
    p       # isPrime
     Z      # max
      Ip    # push isPrime(input)
        *   # multiply
```

Comment: Use `ÌIÍ‚` instead of `40SÍ+` for -1 byte

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 52 bytes

```php
<?=($p=gmp_prob_prime)($n=$argn)&&$p($n+2)|$p($n-2);
```

without GMP, **84 bytes**

(using [my prime function from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39743570))

```php
<?=p($n=$argn)&&p(2+$n)|p($n-2);function p($n){for($i=$n;--$i&&$n%$i;);return$i==1;}
```

Run as pipe with `-nF`. Empty output for falsy, `1` for truthy.

[Dennis´ great solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135300) ported to PHP, **56 bytes**

```php
while($i++<4*$n=$argn)($n+$n%6-3)*$n%$i?:$s++;echo$s==3;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1f6d9fb6f701b41661aa2b3d66d617539f51c93).

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 24 bytes

```
?(*+(0&(-2|2))).is-prime
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPvfXkNLW8NATUPXqMZIU1NTL7NYt6AoMzf1v7VCcWKlQnpRagFQoY5CnKGBgfV/AA)

`*` is the argument to this anonymous function.  `0 & (-2 | 2)` is the junction consisting of the numbers `0` AND either `-2` OR `2`.  Adding `*` to this junction produces the junction of the number `*` AND either of the numbers `* - 2` OR `* + 2`.  Calling the `is-prime` method on this junction returns a truthy value if `*` is prime AND either `* - 2` OR `* + 2` are prime.  Finally, the `?` collapses the truthy junction to a boolean value, satisfying the consistent-return-values condition.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>14 12</s> 11 bytes

```
&P_QP-3+%Q6
```

[Test Suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26P_QP-3%2B%25Q6&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=5%0A7%0A11%0A15%0A20%0A37&debug=0)

---

Saved 3 bytes using the formula in @Dennis' answer. Saved 1 byte thanks to @Dennis.

---

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 14 bytes <sub>**Initial Solution*</sub>

```
&|P_ttQP_hhQP_
```

[Test Suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26%7CP_ttQP_hhQP_&input=9&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A%0A5%0A%0A7%0A%0A11%0A%0A13+%0A%0A17%0A%0A19%0A%0A2%0A%0A15%0A%0A20%0A%0A47%0A%0A9&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
(P=PrimeQ;P@#&&(P[#+2]||P[#-2]))&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfI8A2oCgzNzXQOsBBWU1NIyBaWdsotqYGSOsaxWpqqv0HSueV6Duk6TtUG@somOoomOsoGBoCMZBnCGJb6igYAbExUMwEhI1ruZD0GAFVADUZGQAxUIcxUIcJEFuCdIIETc3Mav8DAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
HOht_v+ZpAa
```

Output is `0` or `1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38M/oyS@TDuqwDHx/39DYwA)

#### Explanation

```
H    % Push 2
O    % Push 0
h    % Concatenate horizontally: gives [2 0]
t_   % Push a negated copy: [-2 0]
v    % Concatenate vertically: [2 0; -2 0]
+    % Add to implicit input
Zp   % Isprime
A    % All: true for columns that only contain nonzeros
a    % Any: true if there is at least a nonzero. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
.*
$*
11(1+)
$1¶$&¶11$&
m`^(11+)\1+$

1<`1¶1
```

Returns 1 if the input is a twin prime, 0 otherwise

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsxDsIwFEP3d45QhVZCdX7TKBI7l6hQGBgYYECcrQfoxcKXPNjP9vf5e30e/RRvrV9GwogUNZ0JOvYwHLsUBt7tHuV00xRA1@alejcyxQ/IkJtKqphYXEZCmTSTDCssheoTz3ld/w)

#### Explanation

```
.*              
$*
```

Convert to Unary

```
11(1+)          
$1¶$&¶11$&
```

Put n-2, n, and n+2 on their own lines

```
m`^(11+)\1+$
```

(Trailing newline) Remove all composites greater than 1

```
1<`1¶1
```

Check if there are two consecutive primes (or 1,3 because 3 is a twin prime)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes`, 42 bytes

```
[| x | 0 2 -2 [ x + prime? ] tri@ or and ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxCsIwFEV3v@LsYpFs6qCbuLiIU@kQasRimoSXB7bQf4@h2z3nwH3bXqOU5@N2vx75OgnOk8SpzkmGoIxWP/jYW5/X3VQ9usyptAsTC3sMO0NbYcsaz3SoDBeiYMOLrpjDJv9sor54mvIH)

Originally inspired by trying to golf [Michael Chatiskatzi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220617/62393), I've then modified it enough that I thought worth posting it as a separate answer.

#### Explanation

This is a lambda function using the local variable `x` to refer to the element at the top of the stack when the function is called (its argument).

`[ x + prime? ]` defines a function that adds `x` to a number and checks if the result is prime. This is then applied using `tri@` to the three values `0`,`2`,`-2`, resulting in three booleans determining if `x`,`x+2` and `x-2` are primes. We combine the last two with `or`, and the result of this with the first with `and`.

The total function is then equivalent to `isprime(x+0) and (isprime(x+2) or isprime(x-2))`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Port of [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135293/47066)

```
6%+ÍIp-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fTFX7cK9ngW7B//9GlgA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##DYoxCoAwEAT7fYUErFTI3eUS4ltsFOxTCQG/4JtS5GFnYIoZGK/nRbe9T60W56V/tWzFquttn3pz62ECRQIRSEBDMjhDCGEgYJCCPVggCSEhj2W0xvgD)

**Explanation**

```
6%         # n mod 6
  +        # add n
   Í       # subtract 2
    Ip-    # subtract isPrime(n)
       p   # isPrime
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>102</s></sub> 100 Bytes

No primality built-ins for VBA <kbd>:(</kbd>

#### Code

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs either `1` (truthy)  or `0` (falsy) to the VBE Immediate window

```vba
a=[A1]:?p(a)*(p(a-2)Or p(a+2))
```

#### Helper Function

```vba
Function p(n)
p=n>2
For i=2To n-1
p=IIf(n Mod i,p,0)
Next
End Function
```

---

### Alternatively, 122 Bytes

#### Code

Recursive primality checking function based solution

```vba
a=[A1]:?-1=Not(p(a,a-1)Or(p(a-2,a-3)*p(a+2,a+1)))
```

#### Helper Function

```vba
Function p(n,m)
If m>1Then p=p(n,m-1)+(n Mod m=0)Else p=n<=0
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <strike>91 bytes</strike>, 81 bytes thanks to [Jared Smith](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59429/jared-smith)

```js
p=n=>{for(i=2;i<n;)if(n%i++==0)return !!0;return n>1},t=n=>p(n)&&(p(n+2)||p(n-2))
```

**Explanation**

`p` tells wether the given number `n` is prime or not, and `t` tests given number `n` and `n±2`.

**Example**

```js
var twinPrimes = [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 29, 31, 41, 43];
var notTwinPrimes = [2, 15, 20, 23, 37, 47, 97, 120, 566];

p=n=>{for(i=2;i<n;)if(n%i++==0)return !!0;return n>1},t=n=>p(n)&&(p(n+2)||p(n-2))

for (var n of twinPrimes) {
  console.log(n, ': ', t(n));
}

for (var n of notTwinPrimes) {
  console.log(n, ': ', t(n));
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `var`, the parentheses around the `n` in the function definition, etc.

Comment: I think you could edit your snippet to show the value of  `n` beside the value of `t(n)` for increased clarity (Eg. `7:   true`)

Comment: Thx to both of you

Answer (score 1):

## J, 23 bytes

```
1&p:*.0<+/@(1 p:_2 2+])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYqxCsJAEAX7@4ohhcQE4u1uLscFBX8kWIhBLGLafP25nfCKecx8al1vA3La526I1/5yb4V9fijaL@dwuDMSGRHEEIeCFkwYfRY2LxRJaEQNy4yZ4pn/NE3h9Xx/WZvI8cet1h8)

#### how?

```
1&p:                               is the arg a prime?
    *.                             boolean and
                                   one of +2 or -2 also a prime
                     (1 p:_2 2+])  length 2 list of booleans indicating if -2 and +2 are primes
               @                   pipe the result into...
      0<+/                         is the sum of the elements greater than 0
                                   ie, at least one true
```

Comment: 16 bytes with `3>0#.@p:0 2 _2&+`

Comment: @miles nice.  very clever use of base 2 to process the results.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 38 + 6 = 44 bytes

Requires options `-rprime`.

```
->n{n.prime?&[n-2,n+2].any?(&:prime?)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmD7X9curzpPr6AoMzfVXi06T9dIJ0/bKFYvMa/SXkPNCiKuWfu/KLWwNLMoVUG9oECdq6BAQcNST8/IWFMvN7FAoVqhpqJGIbpCRyEtuiI2VqH2/7/8gpLM/Lzi/7pFYBMA)

Comment: You can save a byte using `&` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript(ES6), 54 bytes

```
a=x=>f(x)&(f(x+2)|f(x-2));f=(n,x=n)=>n%--x?f(n,x):x==1
```

```js
a=x=>f(x)&(f(x+2)|f(x-2));f=(n,x=n)=>n%--x?f(n,x):x==1


console.log("True")
console.log("---------------------")
console.log(a(3))
console.log(a(5))
console.log(a(7))
console.log(a(11))
console.log(a(13))
console.log(a(17))
console.log(a(19))
console.log(a(29))
console.log(a(31))
console.log(a(41))
console.log(a(43))
console.log("False")
console.log("---------------------")
console.log(a(2))
console.log(a(15))
console.log(a(20))
console.log(a(23))
console.log(a(37))
console.log(a(47))
console.log(a(97))
console.log(a(120))
console.log(a(566))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
j ©[U+2U-2]dj
```

Returns `true` and `false` for whether or not the number is part of a prime twin pair.

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=aiCpW1UrMlUtMl1kag==&inputs=Mg==,Mw==,MTU=,NQ==,MjA=,Nw==,MjM=,MTE=,Mzc=,MTM=)

### Explanation

Implicit: `U` = input integer

```
j ©
```

Check if the input is prime (`j`), AND (`©`) ...

```
[U+2U-2]dj
```

Using the array `[U+2, U-2]`, check if any items are true (`d`) according to the primality function (`j`).

Implicit output of the boolean result of `is input prime AND is any ±2 neighbor prime`.

Comment: Hmm... I feel like `[U+2U-2]` could be much shorter, but I can't figure out how...

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
Vṗ(§e+-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@zhzukah5anausa/f//39AQAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes`, 46 bytes

```
[ dup 2 [ + ] 2keep - [ prime? ] tri@ or and ]
```

**Demonstartion** of every state of the stack for the example number 43:

```
  43   dup    2  [ + ]  2keep    - [ prime? ] tri@   or   and
  
|    |     |    |  + |    2   |    | prime? |      |    |     | 
|    |     |  2 |  2 |   43   | 41 |     41 |    t |    |     | 
|    |  43 | 43 | 43 |   45   | 45 |     45 |    f |  t |     | 
| 43 |  43 | 43 | 43 |   43   | 43 |     43 |    t |  t |   t |
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxCoNAEAV7v@L1ooWxMkXsxCaNWInFohsUz3NZV0K@/nLYDMwwH5rs0NB37bupsLF6dtjJlhu56LrzCVE2@0XxhmcYMF@CAgNSjCg2ZkEW7Z5fMZmuNQ4F@RljKB/J@SXBRM4hD38)

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), <s>48</s> <s>35</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

*-20 bytes thanks to [H.PWiz](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57424541#57424541)*

```
^(xx)?(?!(xx(x*))\3?\2+$)xxx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9bsIwFEZfBaIK7iVNSGjVAddk6sDC0I6llaxwcdwax7INuPw8exqGSp2@4XzS0fkSB@Frp2zIvFUbcrvWfNNP57ih4@CV5Eu0ACe@mE66T4gRK6iG/UKcIK4fqvUsvcMYYzeZnjAP7VtwykjA3GtVEzzdZ4@IzPOCHRulCUBzR2KjlSFAHHKz1xrPkuvcW60CjLMxMrUFMFzmmowMDS5ml4vyK7ECxa1wnpYmgHwvPhD/AP0HZlFW5fyGMTSuPSZLcxBabQZOGEnzQZJqtm0dMPXMiak0xV6YxCR3ZEkEUJjvRKgbcIhnPxrZPinAraJkdh98cP2FXa9dkZVFUfwC) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7BasMwDP0VrZjGWhJid/Qyx00K3XWn3ZbOdKUBg9dmdgYexvv1zM0Ku0h6T096bzhZs54@voFYAcFcjgcDpBIJynq3fdluIvQXS4mTTNQbgQF0nxCGwerzCIvuvBARWiPdYPRIszIr3Ne7G9OJKkpecDx9XkXNP8sSj49Eobj@csnxYFtTrzC05pXvZapsL26@@gaJruW8TlOeY9A9UJr5DDwkESLIH6iIrTAQt1zO4eZsKTgXf1mJFjFGpZ6ed0pNb9R7bGhzlzr194jdQ9OtcoLe@2liJWeM/QI) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9swDHzvr2CNDZGSVHW6t6lGsA0bMGDthuYxzQDFlhO1Mu1JcuO2yG/PKMf7KFC/0CRPR92Jd@pBnd0V9wdTNbULcEe5MLUYS/i/0gZjX605vdEddU6adm1NDrlV3sOVMgjPMNR8UIHCQ20KqKjDFsEZ3IByG79ccQhbV@88fO5y3QRT08kTgC/Gaigz1Lv@lyUirwstqJ9w@bEtS@10caNVoR2se9jLIvtzckhLzuUw10@D3G0jP2M@W5MGVXwzqBnnpxm21nJTMi/0r1ZZz5Lz8XiccP78EnpkYCy8SvBMDOEvAxGcE8OacPfST7LRLY5iDHJ/rO1/qBC0Q3DZ8EdqqyYO8FySG@u6tlohPGUlMWoJi1whknSDTRsgg6h2qLHFow@6Ega5hEFnDxNb5a91F@iavcUAgyGW7k4cRxASYpA49JcrsNSOKOEbawJLzugRCB8AU@p8xUBr4ESjnNeUMLtMV3wKOHu1KazGTdheXsAcIhLeU5itiDHfKrdcdYOePsPZSsIH59SjF6WxlnXTUTfqTQEoaxe10TUyTCXgZYYzCpMJCbxSId@SQxWxOVEdM9ZvLtKCfyLy48aInVMNG0bkdfP4vbxRuNE0KZ0i51FpCayi8ViQd/Ftn/hgck2O7ZwJmsVH5fIpC66N7/Ov3ZCHoWTJW5@QJVzu43cSt@rwk3Udn7P5KUXWjTm/fTe/vZi84V3XHeLWHNKzWZqmvwE) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7RboMwDEXf@Qov6oPdAUraN1jEh1AmVRtdM6UOcjI1/XpGOu3Jls89V14e6Rr4uLrbEiRBfMRa5vo7Bu5BrCil1nfMmQYcXraJeU90Og6nw@uOcs7rFhhN15ipB2d1dQkCHhyXojamT8ddBd76Ni7eJVSNogrcBfzM6Ont0IEfzWT9qKcKisxFljN/zeg4YQFU/21mItraii5zezunjytKDSqrPT9BIa6DRUqengdr@v9Xwk9q7@LSjDEJMtGqG6O1/gU) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BbsIwDIbvewpTTSJha5R2N7KoqqBCuzAJuLUsAhFKpChUaRDZZa/eJWxwsC3//j/b9rL/HixwWMlW@o4YeYV5uSmJlbvD6584nX4slp@ralauKwaKUwbXk9ISNG@l658A1BF0nWZbzpPGJCwMdE0JSfMtA2kOwREU0ndaOTROx/gfIVqa1p0Qfs8DUwc@YA/keLZgQBmIInFnoVBGMSHR@GiD77YLJT6ZGAz8ByyLghrFP7uL62/74t9Z6K0yDsz9RMwxhKiWcyGGL@Q9LlAxChX5CcbNW9HkL8/Yez8MNM0opb8) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDfS8MwEH7fXxFDoLmt29o6lZGVvqggiA/q2zpDV9O1mKUhzaAw9rfX6/DJh1zu1/d9d2drO2wyW1vCHEkJXVKyINapg3TK6qJUPFguppmUdaG9LNujbbRyOc9B5O/LLghJgK/CpDyoscF4ZXzHpXx@eX2SEkISA1IisZg0ppGd8pza0qnFvih/vEMjdXNsPA0JXSXr1fr@IVnfURCTqnWcNWkkmE4rZO/4x@fjyxsIOJOm4kxvO@@0MujBPN6lKc0NBWzuTnusYDqMwnkMI171VrffitM5DbFdIL5sT8aP2E2CoC0SoI12YkLIVdn8xcxs0msdvdkMUJrw64WOhS9rzlyIYuO5VOF50AchMwBAzuOIDaiybse5BMFVYkHGmDAjLihz@XdWDmL44n0PGc9u8Of9FCC/zfJkxqDv@2GI5nEURb8) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBNa@MwEL3vr1BCIZqNbez0tqqagumh0NBlE@hhuwtaZ5oKFNlo5FSNm9@eVey2l8xFDO@N3kdFaVU7PFq1RWpUhWz5Rh63XUvablgpy9pSbVAM@wqDz37hpjXK3YbGIZGOBFEZRcS2HXnldcV2tV6zhdKWceh2yjGSN@PjXx4CzPl8FF8evgM8Xc6fZtMLCCEcx@LEc9LiK4sCGDhly/YfeRd1eZFQdo9241/SGSQ9/tD4k3RW1ttGG1yDGLjMiOfacW09szIX3MgyOlbre22RA4ykbY0RVhbQ6Wdur3Mos0enPQ6E3kYjTbZsjPZ8kk5AnP7SCYpv8aD58HE9e38fRSBbubefyhHy5nf@J6nbSIVz6PMsLQYOwqcsH9/ZnTKxMKfsBn@wLj@MEwMCDWFfXuhLWQ5NTMIk0fAVcR8j6iuJQk@nSZjKCEN06bI7WihfvfAAfc79Wc69LMSXhV4zfHgEcejnmKdFnuf/AQ) - .NET

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number.

Commented and indented:

```
^                 # tail = N = input number
# Assert either that N-2 and N are prime, or that N and N+2 are prime.

(xx)?             # tail -= 2, optionally
# Assert that neither tail nor tail+2 are composite. For testing that they are both prime,
# this has false positives for tail=0, tail=1, and tail=2.
(?!               # Assert that the following can't match:
    (xx(x*))      # \2 = any number >= 2; \3 = \2 - 2
    \3?           # tail -= \3, optionally; if this is done, we're asserting that tail+2 is
                  #             composite (divisible by \2 with a quotient >= 3), otherwise
                  #             we're asserting tail is composite (quotient >= 2).
    \2+$          # Assert that tail is positive and divisible by \2
)
xxx               # Assert that tail >= 3, preventing the false positives.
                  # The "quotient >= 3" requirement above is why tail=2 can be one of them,
                  # as it prevents 2+2 from being seen as composite.
```

### 29 bytes

```
^                  # tail = N = input number
# Assert either that N-2 and N are prime, or that N and N+2 are prime.

(xx)?              # tail -= 2, optionally
# Assert that neither tail nor tail+2 are composite. For testing that they are both prime,
# this has false positives for tail=0 and tail=1.
(?!                # Assert that the following can't match:
    (xx)?          # tail -= 2, optionally; if this is done, we're asserting that tail is
                   #            composite, otherwise we're asserting tail+2 is composite.
    (x*)           # \3 = S-2, where S is a potential divisor to test against M = tail+2;
                   # tail -= \3
    (\3xx)+$       # assert that tail is positive and divisible by \3+2, which is
                   # equivalent to asserting M is divisible by S with a quotient >= 2
)
xx                 # Assert that tail >= 2, preventing the false positives.
```

### 48 bytes

This misses the fact that we can switch between testing N-2 and N or testing N and N+2. Instead, this regex switches between testing N and N-2 or testing N and N+2, which results in tests not having enough in common to be collapsed together.

```
^   # tail = N = input number
(
    # Assert that neither N nor N-2 are composite. But we want N and N-2 to be prime, so
    # this gives false positives for 0, 1, and 2.
    (?!              # Assert that the following can't match:
        (xx)?        # tail -= 2, optionally
        (xx+)        # \3 = any number >= 2
        \3+$         # Assert that tail is positive and divisible by \3
    )
|   # or...
    # Assert that neither N nor N+2 are composite. But we want N and N+2 to be prime, so
    # this gives false positives for 0 and 1.
    (?!              # Assert that the following can't match:
        (xx(x*))     # \4 = any number >= 2; \5 = \4 - 2
        \4*(xx)?\5$  # Assert that either tail or tail+2 is positive and divisible by \4
    )
)
xxx                  # Block the false positives on every number less than 3
```

### 51 bytes (not golfed at all)

```
^                      # tail = N = input number
(?!(xx+)\1+$)          # Assert that N is not composite. But we want N to be prime,
                       # so this gives false positives for 0 and 1.
(
    (?!xx(xx+)\3+$)    # Assert that N-2 is not composite. But we want N-2 to be prime, so this
                       # gives false positives for 0, 1, and 2.
|   # or...
    (?!(x*)(xx\4)+$)   # Assert that N+2 is not composite. Has no false positives for primality.
)
xxx                    # Block the false positives on every number less than 3
```

## Regex (ECMAScript), 67 bytes

Just for kicks, here is a port of [Dennis's Jelly algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135293/47066):

```
^(?!(xx+)\1+$)(?=(x{6})*(x*))xxx(?!(xx+)(?=\4*(x*)).*(?=\5\3$)\4+$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc9Nb8IwDAbgvwIVArtdS7sxDmSB0w5cOGzHdZMiMG22kEZJgIyP394VTZN2tJ/Xst5PcRBubaXxqTNyQ3bX6C/6bi3XdOy9UPUcDMCJz8dx@wGLPoSQYFkkA4QFh3CeXjGGECOGEP64k3Lyu83i2/BYPgywnHRHbTw@YeabV2@lrgAzp@SaYHqXThCZ4zk71lIRgOKWxEZJTYDY53qvFJ4rrjJnlPQwSkfI5BZA8ypTpCtf4/z@cpFuJVYguRHW0VJ7qN7yd8Q/oP@g58WimN0YfW2bY7TUB6HkpmeFrmjWixLFto0FJp84MZkk2D2MQpRZMiQ8SMx2wq9rsIhnNxyarpKHW4uCmb133nYRdr22eVrkef4D)

```
^                      # tail = N = input number
(?!(xx+)\1+$)          # Assert N is not composite
(?=(x{6})*(x*))        # \3 = N % 6
xxx                    # assert N>=3; tail -= 3
# Assert tail + \3 is not composite
(?!                    # Assert the following can't match:
    (xx+)              # \4 cycles through all values such that 2 <= \4 <= tail,
                       #    and is tested as a possible divisor of tail + \3
    (?=\4*(x*))        # \5 = tail % \4
    .*(?=\5\3$)        # tail = \5 + \3
    \4+$               # Assert that tail is positive and divisible by \4
)
```

#### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```
n=>/^(..)?(?!(..(.*))\3?\2+$).../.test(Array(n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1BbsIwEIXhqwCqYKZRjEN3uE7UJRsuUFrJahxnWndi2QaEgLOn6aJSV2/xSe//NCeTPiKFXKZArY3fA3/Zy9jpkXW9fgchsIFmPi2IR8TDU3PYFA8ohFiLbFOGlxjNBbioEMekpTr35C2A19Ga1hNbQJxrPnqPV6e9SMFThlW5QkUdAGsnvGWXe6w3txulvdkD6WBisjvO4F7lG@If2P/AddVU21/G3MfhvNjxyXhqZ9Gws9vZovCqGyIoetZWUVHgFOyAEK9puQyRphdUSVcqHHPKcRJ1v4@yrKSUPw)

## Ruby, 41 bytes

```
->n{?x*n=~/^(xx)?(?!(xx(x*))\3?\2+$)xxx/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NDoIwEITvPsViTGg1LQWPWHkQQBMjP02axUCNNUZfHReiHNruTOebbH@/PMdaj@KIr8xvUX@iE/OeZywL6GV@y3mxz4pkt@He@@g9Gq1SeLTGVmB1U7lhBWBqsLmIS63XBa5T@rC5klIkZQoVXilBjhxu1jgWipD/EGkrbFzL@CEhJieesAWpux4QDMJkStedDYsVl3IKLpJyc1edI4E0mGDa73Z3w9xDno5J9wYd4L96uumMSsRKqS8)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcXBCkVAFAbgvac4U7fMwR3FyoJ5ENyiKAs6ptSv4b768G0@d4xnmKkO32bzFslW//OfBthqq941EuautF2RfhhAfgc37cfiJopF4kiEdGVMUbJZByFPFy5qkZFSc4u@pzs8) - test cases only

#### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 34 bytes

```
.*
$*
^(11)?(?!(11(1*))\3?\2+$)111
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYoxCgIxFAX7uYWwQpIF8f2/2ZAqpZdYRAsLGwvx/vHDg5mB93393p/nPKfbY14KS@GepDzSOAWTSs6Hj8PWJUua06k0JOQopGMdF1vMMVSxK@Z4Y2v0uETXff8D) - test cases only

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 35 bytes

```apl
{∨/2∧/∊∘{(⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳⍵}¨⍨|2(-,⊢,+)⍵}
 ∨/ ⍝ reduce by bitwise OR
   2∧/ ⍝ logical AND bit array, two at a time (overlapping)
     ∊∘{...}¨⍨ ⍝ for each, check if in list of primes
       (⊢~∘.×⍨)1↓⍳⍵ ⍝ find element of range that is not in matrix of composite numbers (list of primes)
         | ⍝ absolute value of array
           2(-,⊢,+)⍵ ⍝ create array (2-n, n, 2+n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqRx0r9I0edSzXf9TR9ahjRrXGo65FdUCG3uHpj3pXaBo@apv8qHfzo96ttYdWAAVqjDR0dYBKdLQ1QWJAQxSMudIUTIHYHIgNDUEESMQQzLUEEkYgwhgkYQImQLJGIEmQJiMDEAESMgZpMAERlmCtYBlTMzMA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 85 bytes **24 bytes  thanks to Mayube**

```
e($n){return f($n)&&((f($n-2)||f($n+2)))
f($n){for($i=$n;--$i&&$n%$i;)return $i==1;}
```

Comment: This can be golfed considerably by changing the names of both functions to 1 character each (eg `a` and `b`)

Comment: Doesn´t PHP need the `function` keyword anymore?

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda x:p(x)*(p(x-2)|p(x+2))
p=lambda z:(z>1)*all(z%i for i in range(2,z))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYmxCoMwFEV3v@IthXetBc0YiF/iErFpH8QkBAcN/nvq4NTlHDgnHds3BlWdmaq367xY2nXiHS1ffCmcl54KaJK5f9FcxgGt9Z7LQ8jFTEISKNvwebPqClD/4tD30A2JI8cCnbKEjaT@AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 84 bytes

Current Excel 365:

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(A1+2),(SUM((MOD(A1,x)=0)*1)=2)*(SUM((MOD(A1+MOD(A1,6)-3,x)=0)*1)=2))
```

Future Excel (73 bytes):

```
=LET(p,LAMBDA(a,SUM((MOD(a,SEQUENCE(a))=0)*1)=2),p(A1)*p(A1+MOD(A1,6)-3))
```