# Find the sum of primes

Tags: code-golf, math

Given a number x, find the sum of all primes up to that number.

The input will always be a positive number, bigger than 2. An upper limit isn't defined, so data types can be ignored. Use whichever you want.

- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Example for 5:

`2 + 3 + 5 = 10`

Test cases:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 17 | 58 |

The input doesn't have to be parsed, so assume you get the "correct" data-type. (`int` in Java, for example)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of [Sum of primes between given range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/113/66833) as the fundamental tasks (generate a range, keep primes, sum) are the same

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
æP
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyVBNlAmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xNyZmbGFncz1T)

##### Explanation

```python
    # Implicit input
æ   # Filter [1..input] by:
 P  #  Prime check
    # Sum the list
    # Implicit output
```